# Using a Variable (PowerShell) inside of a command

Tags: powershell, variables, string-interpolation, quoting

```
$computer = gc env:computername

# Argument /RU '$computer'\admin isn't working.
SchTasks /create /SC Daily /tn "Image Verification" /ST 18:00:00 /TR C:\bdr\ImageVerification\ImageVerification.exe /RU '$computer'\admin /RP password
```

Basically I need to provide the computer name in the scheduled task...

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Variables are not interpolated in strings with single quotes. Use double quotes instead.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Single quoted strings will not expand variables in PowerShell. Try a double quoted string e.g.:

```
"$computer\admin"
```

Comment: Or no quotes at all in this case. PowerShell will handle quoting automatically anyway.

Comment: Yup, that is what I would normally do.  Just wanted to point out the diff between single and double-quoted strings.  :-)

Comment: I get an error: ERROR: Logon Failure: unknown username or password... Yet I know that the user exists any thoughts?  I am doing this correctly?

Comment: If you use /RU it looks like the username needs to be something like "NT AUTHORITY\LocalService".  Perhaps you do not want to use the "run as" account and use just /U and /P instead? Also the time spec should be just 18:00 according the usage.

Answer (score 2):

To complement [Keith Hill's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12394041/45375) with additional information:

**Both `"$computer\admin"` and the *unquoted* form, `$computer\admin`, would work**, because unquoted string arguments are *implicitly* treated as if they were **`"..."`-enclosed** (*double*-quoted), i.e. as **[*expandable strings*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings) that perform *string interpolation*** (replace embedded variable references and expressions with their values), as opposed to [*verbatim strings*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#single-quoted-strings) (**`'...'`**, *single*-quoted) that do *not* interpret their content.

**When in doubt, use `"..."` explicitly**, notably when the string contains metacharacters such as `|` and `<`

For the complete rules on how *unquoted* tokens are parsed as command arguments, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41254359/45375).

**Pitfalls**:

The ***partial* quoting** you attempted:

> `'$computer'\admin`

even if corrected to **`"$computer"\admin`** to make interpolation work, **would *not* work**, because PowerShell - perhaps surprisingly - then passes the value of `$computer` and verbatim string `\admin` as ***two* arguments**. **Only if a compound string with partial quoting *starts with an unquoted string* is it recognized as a *single* argument** (e.g. `$computer"\admin"` would work) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65380907/45375) for more information.

Another notable pitfall is that **only *stand-alone* variable references such as `$computer` and `$env:COMPUTERNAME` can be embedded as-is in `"..."`**; to **embed an *expression*** - which includes property access and indexed access - **or a *command***, you need to **enclose them in `$(...)`**, the [subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#subexpression-operator--). E.g., to embed the value of expression `$someArray[0]` or `$someObj.someProp` in an expandable string, you must use `"$($someArray[0])"` or `"$($someObj.someProp)"` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375) for the complete rules.