# how do I pass a range of values on the command line - passing an expression as an argument

Tags: powershell, parsing, command-line, syntax, parameter-passing

I have the following code:

```
$srv_range = 29..30+40+50..52
$srv_range.GetType()
$NewVMTemplate = New-Object psobject
$NewVMTemplate | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Name -Value $null

$srv_range | % {
    $pod= $_
    $servers = @()
    1..2 | % {
        $server = $NewVMTemplate | Select-Object *
        $server.Name = "pod" + "{0:D2}" -f $pod + "-srv" + $_
        $servers += $server
    }
    ForEach ( $server in $servers) {
        write-host $server.Name
    }
}
```

output:

```
PowerCLI C:\ .\eraseme.ps1

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
pod29-srv1
pod29-srv2
pod30-srv1
pod30-srv2
pod40-srv1
pod40-srv2
pod50-srv1
pod50-srv2
pod51-srv1
pod51-srv2
pod52-srv1
pod52-srv2
```

I want to input the range from CLI, but I get the following output with this code

```
param(

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$False)] $srv_range

)
#$srv_range = 29..30+40+50..52
$srv_range.GetType()
$NewVMTemplate = New-Object psobject
$NewVMTemplate | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Name -Value $null

$srv_range | % {
    $pod= $_
    $servers = @()
    1..2 | % {
        $server = $NewVMTemplate | Select-Object *
        $server.Name = "pod" + "{0:D2}" -f $pod + "-srv" + $_
        $servers += $server
    }
    ForEach ( $server in $servers) {
        write-host $server.Name
    }
} 

PowerCLI C:\ .\eraseme.ps1 29..30+40+50..52

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     String                                   System.Object
pod29..30+40+50..52-srv1
pod29..30+40+50..52-srv2
```

How can I input the range from CLI and get the same result as the first code?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your problem is that argument **`29..30+40+50..52` is treated as a *string literal* in your `.\eraseme.ps1 29..30+40+50..52` call - it is *not* recognized as an *expression*.**

To **force recognition as an *expression*, enclose the argument in `(...)`**, the [grouping operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#grouping-operator--):

```
.\eraseme.ps1 (29..30+40+50..52)
```

The **same applies** if you want to use ***output from (another) command* as a command argument**; e.g.:

```sh
# Pass the lines read from file paths.txt as an array to Get-ChildItem
# (Parameter -Path is implied in both commands).
Get-ChildItem (Get-Content paths.txt)
```

<sup>Two asides:

• `$(...)`, the [subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#subexpression-operator--), is only ever needed in two cases: (a) to embed entire *statement(s)*, notably loops and conditionals, in another statement, and (b) to embed an expression, command, or statement(s) inside `"..."`, an expandable (interpolating) string. Just `(...)` is enough to embed a single *command* or *expression* in a statement (and even that isn't needed on the RHS of a *variable assignment*). While not likely, the unnecessary use of `$(...)` can have side effects - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58248195/45375).

• You can *make your script more robust* by *declaring your parameter with a more specific type*, in which case an attempt to call it with a string would fail right away:

`[Parameter(Mandatory=$False)] [int[]] $srv_range`

(Other optimizations could be applied to your script as well.)</sup>

---

#### Optional background information

**As for when an *unquoted* token is treated as an *expression* or *nested command* vs. an *(expandable) string* in *argument mode*** (see also: [about_Parsing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing)):

- **`(...)`, `$(...)`, and `@(...)` *by themselves* or *at the start* of a token create a *new parsing context***, in which **expressions or even nested commands** can be used:

  - `(...)` is sufficient for a *single* expression or command. `$(...)` (the *subexpression operator*) can enclose *multiple* expressions / commands; so can `@()` (the *array* subexpression operator), and it additionally ensures that its output is always treated as an *array*.
  - Notably, the following expressions are *not* recognized without being enclosed in one of the above:

    - `[...]` (type literals) and access to their members, such as `[Environment]::Version`
    - `..` (range expressions) such as `1..10`
  - If, at the *start of a token*, `(...)`, `$(...)`, or `@(...)` are followed by additional characters, the first additional character is considered the start of a *new, separate argument*.
  - By contrast, if they're *preceded* by an *unquoted literal* or a *variable-only reference*, `$(...)` works like inside `"..."` (an expandable string), `(...)` starts a *new argument* that is an expression, and `@(...)` is taken as literal `@` with `(...)` again starting a new argument that is an expression.
- A `@` followed by the *name of a variable* (e.g., `@params`) containing a collection or hashtable of parameter values initiates [parameter splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting).
- `@{ ... }` can be used to pass a *hashtable literal* (e.g., `@{ key = 'value' }`).
- `{ ... }` creates a script block (`[scriptblock]`).
- ***By themselves* or *at the start of a token*, variable references, including *member access* (property access, method calls, indexing) can be used as-is**:

  - Expressions such as `$HOME`, `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion`, `$someArray[0]`, and `$someString.ToUpper()` *are* recognized, and returned as their inherent type.
- *Without* member access, i.e., with a simple variable reference such as `$HOME`, subsequent characters are (potentially) considered part of the *same* argument that is then interpreted as an *expandable string* - see below.
- *With* member access, the first of any additional characters is considered the start of a *new argument* (e.g., `$foo.Length-more` results in *two* arguments: the value of `$foo.Length` and string literal `-more`).
- **Everything else is treated as an *expandable string***, i.e., *similar* to the contents of a double-quoted string, *except* that **metacharacters<sup>[1]</sup> still need escaping** and **certain tokens are interpreted as *multiple* arguments**.

  - *Expandable* means that **embedded *simple* variable references** (e.g., `$HOME\Desktop` or `$env:APPDATA\Test`) are interpolated (replaced with their stringified values).
    Note that this can result in a representation that differs from a given value's default output format as shown in the console, for instance (again, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375) for more information).

    - Enclose a variable name in `{...}` to disambiguate it from subsequent characters, if necessary (e.g., `${HOME}`).
  - **To access a variable value's *property* or use an *index* or call a *method* or embed *arbitrary commands*, you must enclose the expression in `$(...)`**, e.g., `v$($PSVersionTable.PSVersion)`
  - Generally, **it is safest to enclose tokens with embedded variable references / expressions in `"..."`**, because it avoids the following edge cases:
    * **`$(...)` at the *start* of an unquoted token is *not* interpreted as part of an expandable string**, it is treated as a *separate argument* (e.g., `Write-Output $('ab')c` results in *two* arguments: the result of `$('ab')` and literal `c`).
    * **`.` at the *start* of a token *immediately followed by a simple variable reference or subexpression* results in *separate arguments* too**.
    (E.g., `.$HOME` results in *two* arguments: literal `.`, and the value of `$HOME`)

    - Note: Even though the result of the expansion is a string, it doesn't necessarily *remain* one: the **final type is determined by the type of to the parameter** of the command at hand to which the expanded value is bound.
    - **Escaping / quoting:**

      - PowerShell has many more metacharacters than `cmd.exe`, and a **notable pitfall is that `,` must be escaped** to be treated a literal, because `,` is PowerShell's array-construction operator.
    - To **escape a *single* character**, prefix it with **`` ` `` (backtick)**.
    - To **avoid the need for escaping metacharacters *individually***, enclose the value in **`"..."` (double quotes)** or **`'...'` (single quotes)**:

      - **Use *double quotes* if you want the string to be *interpolated* (expanded)**, i.e., if you want to be able to embed variable references and subexpressions.

        - *Inside* a double-quoted string, `` ` ``-escape the following chars. to treat them as literals:  `` ` " $ ``
      - **Use *single quotes* to treat the value as a *literal***.

        - *Inside* a single-quoted string, escape a `'`  as `''`
    - Single- or double-quoting is usually the easiest way to escape *spaces* in a value.
- Finally, note that **`--%`**, the so-called **stop-parsing symbol** (PSv3+), completely changes the interpretation of all remaining arguments: designed for use with legacy `cmd.exe` command lines, it **stops interpreting the rest of the line except for expansion of `cmd.exe`-style `%...%` environment variables**. See [`Get-Help about_Parsing`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847892.aspx)

---

**As for using *quoted* tokens:**

- `'...'` or `"..."` *by themselves* or *at the start of a token*:

  - These are parsed as as usual: as a literal (`'...'`) or expandable (`"..."`) string.
  - Any additional characters cause the first additional character to be considered the start of a *new, separate argument*.
- `'...'` or `"..."` being *preceded* by an *unquoted literal* or *variable-only reference*:

  - They are evaluated as usual and the result (i.e., with quotes removed) is appended to what precedes them (evaluated to).

---

<sup>[1] The **argument-mode metacharacters** (characters with special syntactic meaning) are:

`` <space> ' " ` , ; ( ) { } | & < > @ # ``.

Of these, `< > @ #` are only special at the *start* of a token.</sup>

---

**Examples**

```
Write-Output 1..10    # STRING: -> '1..10'
Write-Output (1..10)  # EXPRESSION: -> @(1, 2, ...)
# Write-Output $(1..10) would work too, but is only necessary if 
# the enclosed expression comprises *multiple* statements.

Write-Output [Environment]::Version  # STRING: -> '[Environment]::Ticks'
Write-Output ([Environment]::Version)  # EXPRESSION: -> a [System.Version] instance.

Write-Output a,b    # !! ARRAY @(1, 2), because "," is not escaped.
Write-Output a`,b   #`# STRING 'ab'                                 
Write-Output "a,b"  # ditto
Write-Output 'a,b'  # ditto

Write-Output $HOME\Desktop   # EXPANDED string (e.g.) 'C:\Users\jdoe\Desktop'
Write-Output "$HOME\Desktop" # ditto
Write-Output '$HOME\Desktop' # LITERAL string '$HOME\Desktop'
Write-Output dir=$HOME       # EXPANDED string (e.g.) 'dir=C:\Users\jdoe\Desktop'

Write-Output $PSVersionTable.PSVersion           # a [System.Version] instance
Write-Output "$($PSVersionTable.PSVersion)/more" # a [string]; e.g., '5.1.14393.576/more'
Write-Output "v$($PSVersionTable.PSVersion)"     # ditto; e.g., 'v5.1.14393.576'

# !!! These DO NOT WORK as intended.
Write-Output $($PSVersionTable.PSVersion)/more # $(...) at the *start*
Write-Output $PSVersionTable.PSVersion/more    # $(...) missing
Write-Output "$PSVersionTable.PSVersion/more"  # $(...) missing
Write-Output .$HOME # Specifically, .$ at the beginning is the problem; escaping . works
```