# Calling echo with a single expandable string unexpectedly results in output with a newline in the middle

Tags: powershell

I have the following PowerShell script

```
$var = 'abcd'
echo $($var):123:zzz > test.txt
```

After execution, the content of *test.txt* becomes

```
abcd
:123:zzz
```

How can I avoid newline after `abcd`?

I mean I want the content of *test.txt* to be

```
abcd:123:zzz
```

How can I do this?

Comment: `'$($var):123:zzz' > test.txt` or "$var`:wetwet:ew" > test.txt

Comment: I found that `"$($var):123:zzz" > test.txt` works for me.

Comment: @Seth: The original question title was a bit ambiguous; this question is _not_ about omitting a trailing newline from the output. To your point: `Write-Host` output cannot be redirected on PSv4-. In PSv5+, `Out-File` and `Set-Content` / `Add-Content` support `-NoNewline` as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`echo` is an *alias* for the `Write-Output` cmdlet which is *not necessary* here at all. Just put the desired ouput into the pipeline and pipe it to the `Set-Content` cmdlet:

```
"$($var):123:zzz" | Set-Content -Path 'test.txt' -Encoding Unicode
```

Now, if you want to **append** another string to the file, use the `Add-Content` cmdlet:

```
"anotherLine" | Add-Content test.txt -Encoding Unicode
```

Comment: My `test.txt` becomes empty after I execute `"$var:123:zzz" | Set-Content -Path 'test.txt'`

Comment: Does the version of powershell matter?
My powershell's version is 2.0

Comment: No, this will also work for PowerShell 2.0. Try my edited answer again.

Comment: @mklement0 I didn't thought about the encoding at all. Changed it now - thank you. Please feel free to edit my answers if you find such things, I trust you.

Comment: @MartinBrandl Thanks for updating; I appreciate the offer to edit your answers myself.

Answer (score 1):

[Martin Brandl's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41847092/45375) ***bypasses* your problem with a solution that is preferable anyway** (no need for `Write-Output` a.k.a `echo`).
**This answer *explains* the problem** with your approach.

**tl;dr**

- Use *double quotes*:

  - `echo "$($var):123:zzz" > test.txt`
- Simplified (no need for `echo`):

  - `"$($var):123:zzz" > test.txt`
- Simplest (note the `{}`, which are needed to disambiguate the variable name):

  - `"${var}:123:zzz" > test.txt`
  - `` "$var`:123:zzz" > test.txt `` would work too (escaping the `:`)

---

Your specific problem is that **`$($var):123:zzz` is parsed as *2* arguments, due to not being enclosed in `"`.**

In other words: **The following 2 statements are equivalent**:

```
echo $($var):123:zzz

echo $($var) :123:zzz
```

Both yield the following (wether in the console or when redirected to a file), because `Write-Output` (that `echo` is an alias for) writes its (stringified) arguments separated by a line break:

```
abcd
:123:zzz
```

Since you're passing `$($var):123:zzz` as an *argument* to the `echo` (`Write-Output`) command, it is parsed in [*argument mode*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

In argument mode, an unquoted subexpression-operator expression such as `$($var)` at the start of a token is always treated as a separate argument, even if followed directly by more characters.

<sup>[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41254359/45375) of mine has more information about how PowerShell parses unquoted tokens in argument mode.</sup>

By contrast, *double-quoting* (enclosing the token in `"..."`) ensures parsing as a *single* argument (though note that the subexpression will then be *stringified* first).

Thus, this command would work:

```
echo "$($var):123:zzz" > test.txt
```

Or, more simply, given that PowerShell outputs an expression's result *by default* (`Write-Output` is usually not needed):

```
"$($var):123:zzz" > test.txt
```

Note that while double-quoted strings are used in both commands, the latter command is technically parsed in [*expression mode*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing) (which is PowerShell's other, programming language-like parsing mode), because the command line starts with a `"`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to add ":123:zzz" to the end of $var you can do this as well;

```
$var = 'abcd'
echo ($var+':123:zzz') > test.txt
```

or if you want to add a new line (append) add a second ">";

```
$var = 'abcd'
echo ($var+':123:zzz') >> test.txt
```