# Passing path scripting variable to sqlcmd when called using Invoke-Expression

Tags: powershell, sqlcmd

I'm trying to create a powershell script that creates a database. The relevant part of the createDb.ps1 is:

```
param([string] $server,
      [string] $dbName)
$scriptpath = "C:\script\path" 
$cDb = "master"
$line = "script.sql"
$outfile = "\log.txt"
$dbDir = "C:\database path\"
$command = @"
sqlcmd -b -S $server -d $cDb -i '$scriptpath\$line' -o '.$outfile' -v dbLocation='$dbDir' dbName=$dbName
"@

Invoke-Expression $command
```

I call the script with the following parameters:

```
createDb.ps1 -server localhost -dbName TestDb
```

However when I run this I get the following error:

```
sqlcmd: 'dbDir=C:\database path\" dbName=TestDb': Invalid argument. Enter '-?' for help.
```

When I execute the following from the command line, everything works as expected:

```
sqlcmd -b -S localhost -d master -i "C:\script\path\script.sql" -o ".\log.txt" -v dbLocation="C:\database path\" dbName=TestDb
```

Comment: Not sure why you're using PowerShell, but "shelling out" to SQLCMD, when you could use the MSSQL PowerShell extensions (SQLPS)...?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken you need to do an additional installation beyond the default SQL Server installation in order to use it. Whereas sqlcmd comes with the default SQL Server installation. Since the script can be run on many servers I wanted to minimize the setup required. If this is not the case, then that could be a good option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Do not build your command line as a *string* first and then pass it to `Invoke-Expression`** - not only is it unnecessary, it causes problems with argument partitioning.

**Invoke the command *directly***:

```
sqlcmd -b -S $server -d $cDb -i $scriptpath\$line -o ".$outfile" -v dbLocation=`"$dbDir`" `
  dbName=$dbName
```

Note how `".$outfile"` and `` dbLocation=`"$dbDir`" `` require special treatment:

- Due to a [PowerShell parsing quirk](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42100211/45375) (as of PSv5.1), `.$` at the start of an unquoted token causes it to be broken into *2* arguments. Enclosing `.$outfile` in `"..."` prevents that problem.
- After PowerShell has parsed your command, it essentially *rebuilds* the command line with *selective double-quoting of arguments* before passing it to the system for execution.  While this usually works as desired, there are edge cases, such as `dbLocation=$dbDir`:

  - Since the value of `$dbDir` - `C:\database path\` - contains *spaces*, PowerShell would enclose the expanded result of `dbLocation=$dbDir` in `"..."` to ensure that it is recognized as a *single* argument, which yields `"dbLocation=C:\database path\"` - and `sqlcmd` *may* balk at that.
  - By explicitly *embedding* double quotes in the token - using `` `" ``, which are *escaped* `"` chars. - PowerShell leaves the expanded result of `` dbLocation=`"$dbDir`" `` alone, which yields: `dbLocation="C:\database path\"`
  - **Caveat**:

    - **Most target programs interpret `\"`** not as having *syntactic* function (in this case: *not* as a closing `"` that happens to be preceded by a `\`), but **as an *escaped, embedded* `"`** resulting in **broken argument parsing** - depending on the target program, you may have to escape that final `\` - or possibly all `\` instances - as `\\`.
    - *It is important to understand that on Windows it is ultimately always up to the target program to interpret the command line*; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4094897/45375) for more information.

**Generally:**

- **Variable references do *not* need double-quoting when they serve as arguments** passed to an external utility, even when the referenced variables' values contain spaces (or other metacharacters).

  - That said, routinely double-quoting tokens that *combine* variable references with literals / other variable references is a good habit to form (e.g, `"$scriptpath\$line"` and `".$outfile"`), because the precise rules when such tokens would otherwise be considered *multiple* arguments are not easy to remember - see the link at the bottom.
- However, **you need to be aware of unquoted instances of PowerShell's own metacharacters** - such as `,` in general, and `@` at the start of a token - and **`` ` ``-escape them** to use them as literals (not an issue in the case at hand).
- The **quoting style matters only to *PowerShell*** - once PowerShell has performed its own parsing and possibly expanded variable references, the then-literal tokens are reassembled into a command line that uses *double quotes as needed* behind the scenes to preserve argument boundaries, even if the original command line comprised single-quoted tokens.

  - For instance, PowerShell command line `foo.exe 'bar baz' $env:ProgramFiles $env:OS` would translate to `foo.exe "bar baz" "C:\Program Files" Windows_NT` on invocation of `foo.exe`.
    Note how double-quoting is employed on demand for the values with embedded spaces, irrespective of what quoting was used in the original command line.

For a comprehensive discussion of how PowerShell parses arguments, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41254359/45375) of mine.

Comment: Thanks for the info, that cleared a lot up for me. However, this still didn't fix my issue. I think it has to do with my -v options. I read somewhere that invoking sqlcmd with multiple '=' through powershell causes problems. Do you know if that is true and if so if there is a way to get around it and still have multiple scripting variables?

Comment: Turns out it was a combination of the SQL script and my invocation that was wrong. As your answer solved my issue with the powershell script, I'll mark this as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: @CSCoder: Thanks - I just added a significant update to my answer, shortly after you accepted - I hope I haven't made things worse; do let me know if so.

Answer (score 0):

Use double quotes instead to surround your attribute values when running sqlcmd:

```
$command = @" 
    sqlcmd -b -S $server -d $cDb -i "$scriptpath\$line" -o ".$outfile" -v dbLocation="$dbDir" dbName=$dbName 
"@
```

Comment: This does not work either.. I get the same error message.

Comment: Maybe also give those two variables their own -v switch (e.g. `-v dbLocation="$dbDir" -v dbName=$dbName`).