# Understanding hashtable and splatting in PowerShell 5.1

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell

I am using PowerShell 5.1.

I'm having trouble understanding hashtable and splatting. When splatting are using a hash table to do that or is it something completely different?

I have the following code:

```
$hashtable1 = @{}       
$hashtable1.add('PROD',@{ FirstName = 'John'; LastName = 'Smith'})

function Main() {
    $sel = $hashtable1['PROD']
    
    Function1 $sel    
    Function2 @sel
}

function Function1([hashtable] $x) {
    "Value: $($x.LastName)"
    $x.FirstName
}

function Function2([string] $firstName) {
    "Value: $($firstName)"
}

Main
```

[image]

Comment: What I've used and sent on: See if this edification helps: [PowerShell Hash Table vs. PSCustomObject: Deep Dive & Comparison](https://jeffbrown.tech/powershell-hash-table-pscustomobject/), [Powershell: Everything you wanted to know about hashtables](https://powershellexplained.com/2016-11-06-powershell-hashtable-everything-you-wanted-to-know-about/), [How to use Hashtable splatting in PowerShell?](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-use-hashtable-splatting-in-powershell)

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly are you asking. I see the screenshot and the code but im not sure which part of the code are you having trouble to understand

Comment: Is your question whether `$hashtable1` and `$hashtable1['PROD']` are both hashtables? The answer to that is: yes

Comment: is this a hashtable ```@{ FirstName = 'John'; LastName = 'Smith'}```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's good information in the existing answers, but let me attempt a focused summary:

The answer to **your actual question** is:

- Yes, `@{ FirstName = 'John'; LastName = 'Smith' }` is a [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables) too, namely in the form of a declarative **hashtable *literal*** - just like `@{}` is an *empty* hashtable literal (it constructs an instance that initially has no entries).

  - A hashtable literal consists of zero or more key-value pairs, with `=` separating each key from its value, and pairs being separated with `;` or newlines.
  - Keys usually do not require *quoting* (e.g. `FirstName`), except if they contain special characters such as spaces or if they're provided via an *expression*, such as a variable reference; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62762938/45375) for details.
- This contrasts with **adding entries to a hashtable *later*, *programmatically***, as your `$hashtable1.Add('PROD', ...)` method call exemplifies (where `PROD` is the entry *key*, and `...` is a placeholder for the entry *value*).

  - Note that a more convenient a**lternative to using the [`.Add()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Hashtable.Add) method is to use an *index expression* or even *dot notation*** (property-like access), though note that it situationally either *adds* an entry or *updates an existing one*: `$hashtable1['PROD'] = ...` or `$hashtable1.PROD = ...`

---

The answer to the **broader question implied by your question's *title***:

- **PowerShell's [hashtables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables)** are a kind of **data structure** often called a [***dictionary*** or, in other languages, ***associative array** or **map***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array). Specifically, they are **case-insensitive** instances of the .NET `[hashtable]` ([`System.Collections.Hashtable`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Hashtable)) type, which is a collection of ***unordered* key-value pair entries**. Hashtables enable efficient lookup of values by their associated keys.

  - Via syntactic sugar `[ordered] @{ ... }`, i.e. by placing `[ordered]` before a hashtable literal, PowerShell offers a **case-insensitive *ordered*** dictionary that maintains the entry-definition order and allows access by *positional* index in addition to the usual key-based access. Such ordered hashtables are case-insensitive instances of the .NET [`System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary) type.

    - A quick example:

      ```bash
      # Create an ordered hashtable (omit [ordered] for an unordered one).
      $dict = [ordered] @{ foo = 1; bar = 'two' }

      # All of the following return 'two'
      $dict['bar'] # key-based access
      $dict.bar    # ditto, with dot notation (property-like access)
      $dict[1]     # index-based access; the 2nd entry's value.
      ```
- **[Splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Splatting)** is an **argument-passing technique** that **enables passing arguments *indirectly***, via a *variable* containing a data structure encoding the arguments, which is useful for dynamically constructing arguments and making calls with many arguments more readable.

  - *Typically* and robustly - but only **when calling *PowerShell* commands with *declared parameters*** - that data structure is a ***hashtable***, whose entry keys must match the *names* of the target command's parameters (e.g., key `Path` targets parameter `-Path`) and whose entry values specify the *value* to pass.

    - In other words: This form of splatting uses a hashtable to implement **passing *named* arguments** (parameter values preceded by the name of the target parameter, such as `-Path /foo` in *direct* argument passing).
    - A quick example:

      ```bash
       # Define the hashtable of arguments (parameter name-value pairs)
       # Note that File = $true is equivalent to the -File switch.
       $argsHash = @{ LiteralPath = 'C:\Windows'; File = $true }

       # Note the use of "@" instead of "$"; equivalent to:
       #   Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath 'C:\Windows' -File
       Get-ChildItem @argsHash
      ```
  - Alternatively, an ***array*** may be used for splatting, comprising parameter *values* only, which are then passed *positionally* to the target command.

    - In other words: This form of splatting uses an array to implement **passing *positional* arguments** (parameter *values only*).
    - This form is typically only useful:

      - when **calling PowerShell scripts or functions that do not formally declare parameters** and access their - invariably *positional* - arguments via the [automatic `$args` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#args)
      - when **calling *external programs***; note that from PowerShell's perspective there's no concept of *named* arguments when calling external programs, as PowerShell's knows nothing about the parameter syntax in that case, and all arguments are simply placed on the process command line one by one, and it is up to the target program to interpret them as parameter names vs. values.
    - A quick example:

      ```bash
       # Define an array of arguments (parameter values)
       $argsArray = 'foo', 'bar'

       # Note the use of "@" instead of "$", though due to calling an
       # *external program* here, you may use "$" as well; equivalent to:
       #   cmd /c echo 'foo' 'bar'              
       cmd /c echo @argsArray
      ```

Answer (score 1):

@postanote has some very good links about hashtables and splatting and are good reads. Taking your examples, you have two **different** functions. One to handle hashtables as a parameter, and the second one that can only handle a single string parameter. The hashtable cannot be used to pass parameters to the second function, e.g.:

```
PS C:\> Function2 $sel
Value: System.Collections.Hashtable
```

Conceptually, the real difference between using hashtables and splatting is not about how you are using them to pass information and parameters to functions, but **how the *functions* and their *parameters* *receive* the information**.

Yes, certain functions can have hashtables and arrays as parameters, but, typically in 98% of the cases, functions **don't** use hashtables as a named parameter to get its values.

For ex. `Copy-Item` doesn't use hash tables as a parameter. If it did, would you want to do this every time you want to copy anything:

```
$hashtable = @{
  Path = "C:\Temp\myfile.txt",
  Destination = "C:\New Folder\"
}
Copy-Item -Parameters $hashtable
```

No, instead, you want the parameters as strings, so you can make it a much easier one liner:

```
Copy-Item -Path "C:\Temp\myfile.txt" -Destination "C:\New Folder\"
```

It makes more sense to most people to deal with individual `strings` as opposed to a generic, large, hashtable "config" to pass. Also, by separating the parameters as separate strings, integers, floats, chars, etc. it is also easier to do validation, default values, mandatory/not mandatory parameters, etc.

Now despite saying all that, there is a situation where you have certain functions with lots of parameters (e.g. sending an email message), or you want to do something multiple times (e.g. copying/moving lots of files from a CSV file). In that case, using a hashtable, and/or arrays, and/or arrays of hashtables, would be useful.

This is where splating comes in. It takes a hashtable and instead of treating it like you are passing a single value (i.e. why `Function2 $sel` returns `System.Collections.Hashtable`), the `@` signt tells PowerShell that it is a collection of values, and to use the collection to try and match to the parameters of the function. That's why passing the hashtable to `Function2` doesn't work, but splatting works e.g.:

```
PS C:\> Function2 @sel
Value: John
```

In this case, it takes the hashtable `$sel` and by using splatting `@sel` PowerShell now knows to not pass the hashtable as-is, but to open up the collection and to matche the `$sel.FirstName` to the `-Firstname` parameter.