# In powershell spawn notepad++ when file to open has spaces in it

Tags: powershell

```
$npp = "C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe";

$myfiles = @(
    "C:\bad boys\file1.txt",
    "C:\bad boys\file2.txt",
    "C:\bad boys\file3.txt"
)

foreach ($file in $myfiles) {
    Start-Process -FilePath $npp -ArgumentList "$file" -PassThru  -NoNewWindow | out-null
}
```

This almost works... except, It doesn't open in notepad++ because it sees the space in the file name and thinks this is where the file path ends... thus, i am unable to open my file list.  Any Ideas how to fix?  What i get instead is notepad++ asking many times if I want to create the file "C:\bad"

Comment: Just single quotes should do it I think

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon, no, when you use `Start-Process`, only double-quoting is supported (unless a given target executable happens to recognize single-quoting on its command line, but that is the exception).

Answer (score 5):

**tl;dr**

While [Joel Coehoorn's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71271265/45375) provides an effective solution to your `Start-Process` problem (which stems from the bug detailed below), you can simplify your code to:

```bash
foreach ($file in $myfiles) {
  # Note: | Out-Null is a trick that makes calling *GUI* applications
  #       *synchronous* (makes PowerShell wait for them to exit).
  & $npp $file | Out-Null
}
```

---

You're seeing a **long-standing bug in [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process)** that causes it to *blindly space-concatenate* its `-ArgumentList` (`-Args`) arguments *without using required embedded double-quoting for arguments with spaces* when forming the single string encoding all arguments that is passed to the target executable behind the scenes.

- See [GitHub issue #5576](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5576), which also discusses that a fix will require a *new parameter* so as not to break backward compatibility.

For that reason, **the required embedded double-quoting must be performed *manually*** as shown in Joel's answer.

**When passing *multiple* arguments, it is ultimately easier to pass a *single* string to 
`-ArgumentList`, with *embedded double-quoting*** as necessary - essentially by formulating a string similar to how you would pass multiple arguments from `cmd.exe`:

E.g., if you were to pass *two* file paths with spaces to Notepad++ at once, you would do:

```bash
Start-Process -Wait -FilePath $npp -ArgumentList "`"C:\bad boys\file1.txt`" `"C:\bad boys\file2.txt`""
```

Alternatively, **since your argument string doesn't require *string interpolation***, you could **use a *verbatim* (single-quoted) string instead**, which avoids the need for escaping the embedded `"` as `` `" ``:

```bash
Start-Process -Wait -FilePath $npp -ArgumentList '"C:\bad boys\file1.txt" "C:\bad boys\file2.txt"'
```

Using a **[here-string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#here-strings)** is yet another option that avoids the need to escape, and can additionally make the call more readable (also works with single quotes (`@'<newline>...<newline>'@`):

```bash
Start-Process -Wait -FilePath $npp -ArgumentList @"
  "C:\bad boys\file1.txt" "C:\bad boys\file2.txt"
"@
```

Also note the overall simplification of the `Start-Process` call:

- Use of `-Wait` to ensure *synchronous* execution (waiting for Notepad++ to exit before continuing).

  - It looks like this is what you *tried* to do by combining `-PassThru` with piping to `Out-Null`, but that doesn't actually work, because that only waits for `Start-Process` itself to exit (which itself - unlike the launched process - executes synchronously anyway).
- The omission of the unnecessary `-NoNewWindow` parameter, which only applies to starting *console* applications (in order to prevent opening a new *console* window); Notepad++ is a *GUI* application.

Note that **the only good reason to use `Start-Process` here - rather than *direct* invocation - is the need for *synchronous* execution: `Start-Process -Wait` makes launching GUI applications synchronous (too), whereas with direct invocation only *console* applications execute synchronously**.

If you didn't need to wait for Notepad++ to exit, ***direct invocation* would make your quoting headaches would go away**, as the required embedded quoting is then *automatically* performed behind the scenes:<sup>[1]</sup>

```bash
foreach ($file in $myfiles) {
  & $npp $file # OK, even with values with spaces
}
```

However, **the `| Out-Null` trick *can* be used effectively in *direct* invocation to make calling GUI applications synchronous**<sup>[2]</sup>, which leads us to the solution at the top:

```bash
foreach ($file in $myfiles) {
  & $npp $file | Out-Null  # Wait for Notepad++ to exit.
}
```

---

<sup>[1] However, up to at least PowerShell 7.2.x, *other* quoting headaches can still arise, namely with empty-string arguments and arguments whose values contain `"` chars. - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59036879/45375).</sup>

<sup>[2] `Out-Null` automatically makes PowerShell wait for the process in the previous pipeline segment to exit, so as to ensure that all input can be processed - and it does so irrespective of whether the process is a console-subsystem or GUI-subsystem application. Since GUI applications are normally detached from the calling console and therefore produce no output there, `Out-Null` has no ill effects. In the rare event that a GUI application *does* explicitly attach to the calling console and produce output there, you can use `| Write-Output` instead (which also works if there's *no* output, but is perhaps more confusing).</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Try quotes around the file paths within the string data:

```
$myfiles = @( 
    "`"C:\bad boys\file.txt`"", 
    "`"C:\bad boys\file2.txt`"",
    "`"C:\bad boys\file3.txt`""
)
```