# Obtain and use UAC credential in Powershell to run job

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm writing a configuration script that has to do a few things that require UAC approval, and I was hoping ideally to achieve approximating "$session = sudo -v" so that I can mix elevated/non-elevated and not require the user to sit at the screen for the 15-30 minutes setup takes just in-case it needs another approval.

Ideally, I'm trying to avoid opening a new console/terminal window since this both loses output and causes screen-flashing that could be problematic for some of my users.

Which suggests that what I may want to do is Start-Job with a credential so that I can wait for completion and retrieve the output.

So now I have two problems:

1. Is there a way to in-session store the user's UAC consent, e.g by using it to get a credential I can reuse?
2. What Start- or Invoke- command can I use to run a scriptblock with the elevation that won't convert the block to a string?

My attempts to use a ScriptBlock failed because of the need to multiply-escape strings that are going into a ScriptBlock construction:

```
{ [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("TEST", "OK", "Machine") }
```

fails for me when I try to pass it to `Start-Process -verb runAs powershell -ArgumentList @('-NoLogo', '-NoProfile', '-Command', $ScriptBlock)`:

```
At line:1 char:46
+ [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable(TEST, OK, Machine)
+                                              ~
Missing ')' in method call.
At line:1 char:46
+ [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable(TEST, OK, Machine)
+                                              ~~~~
Unexpected token 'TEST' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:50
+ [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable(TEST, OK, Machine)
+                                                  ~
Missing argument in parameter list.
At line:1 char:63
+ [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable(TEST, OK, Machine)
+                                                               ~
Unexpected token ')' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingEndParenthesisInMethodCall
```

or if I try to use `System.Diagnostics.Process`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- No, there is no way to cache a UAC confirmation, unfortunately.

  - Conceivably - though I don't think it is worth it - you could start a single, elevated session in the background in which you roll your own IPC, such as by reading commands from a file and saving the results back to a different file, in coordination with the foreground session.
- Invocation with elevation requires the use of [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process), with `-Verb RunAs`, and `Start-Process` fundamentally only supports *string* arguments (a process command line).

  - A string that is to be passed to the PowerShell CLI's (possibly positionally implied) `-Command` / `-c` parameter requires `"` chars. that are to be preserved as part of the command being passed to be escaped as `\"` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61124361/45375) for an explanation); applied to your call:

    ```
    Start-Process -Verb RunAs powershell -ArgumentList @(
      '-NoLogo', 
      '-NoProfile', 
      '-Command', 
      "`"$($ScriptBlock -replace '"', '\"')`""
    )
    ```
  - *Caveat*: While passing the pass-through arguments *individually* to `-ArgumentList`, as above, may be conceptually preferable, a [long-standing bug](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5576) unfortunately makes it better to encode all arguments in a *single string* - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71271756/45375); the bug is also the reason for enclosing the `-Command` argument explicitly in (outer, unescaped) embedded `"` above; while it'll typically work without that, it prevents runs of multiple spaces from getting folded into a single space, which could matter in embedded string literals.