# Start cmd from powershell with multiple arguments

Tags: powershell, cmd, arguments

Currently, I am able to call cmd from powershell using the following command:

```
Start-Process cmd -ArgumentList '/K "ping 192.168.1.1"'
```

What I am trying to do is add multiple arguments to pass onto the command, but it is not working. For example:

```
Start-Process cmd -ArgumentList '/K "title test" /K "ping 192.168.1.1"'
```

Is there a way to do this?

Edit: My goal is to have a cmd window open, pinging the address listed, but also to pass the "title" argument so the window is titled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're calling `cmd.exe`, use its statement-sequencing operator, `&`, to pass multiple commands to `cmd /K`:

```
Start-Process cmd -ArgumentList '/K title test & ping 192.168.1.1'
```

Note:

- [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process)'s `-ArgumentList` (`-Args`) parameter technically accepts an *array* of arguments. While passing pass-through arguments *individually* may be conceptually preferable, a [long-standing bug](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5576) unfortunately makes it better to encode all arguments in a *single string* - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71271756/45375).
- `cmd.exe`'s built-in `title` command inexplicably *includes* double quotes in the title if you enclose the argument in `"..."`; thus, if you want to specify a title that contains *spaces*, leave it unquoted and escape metacharacters other than spaces with `^`; e.g., to pass `test & more` as the title, use `title test ^& more`

Answer (score 1):

start-process is sometimes tricky... try to add the elements as strings to an array and pass it over to start-process.

But in your case... idk what that /K should do, but in case of ping - ping is the process to start, not cmd ;-)

```
start-process ping.exe -argumentlist "127.0.0.1"

start-process ping.exe -argumentlist "127.0.0.1 /t"
```

as you are already using PowerShell

```
test-connection 127.0.0.1
```

Here is an example where I did something simliar:

```
$cmdArray = @(
                If ($token){
                    "-c"
                    "`"http.extraHeader=Authorization: Bearer $token`""
                }
                If ($clone){
                    'clone'
                }
                If ($fetch){
                    'fetch'
                    '-f'
                    'origin'
                    If ($tag){
                        "tags/$($tag):tags/$($tag)"
                    }
                }
                Else {
                    "`"$uri`""
                }
                If ($whatif){
                    '--dry-run'
                }
            )
            $result = Start-Process $pathGitexe -ArgumentList $cmdArray -Wait -NoNewWindow -PassThru
```

ok, based on your comment you need this:

```
$ips = @("192.168.1.1","192.168.1.2")

$ips | %{
    start-process ping.exe -ArgumentList $_
}
```

Comment: I wanted to use powershell to open cmd so i can only multiple ping windows all at once so i can track the ping of a few things at the same time.

Comment: Your edit does work, but I need to be able to rename the title of the cmd window by using another command. Not sure how to accomplish that.

Comment: `cmd /K <command-line>` allows you to open an interactive`cmd.exe` session that executes `<command-line>` on startup (`/C`, by contrast, exits the session after executing the command line). Thus, since the goal is to pass _multiple_ statements as part of `<command-line>`, they can simply be separated with `&`.