# Install setup.exe in PowerShell with Arguments

Tags: powershell, parameter-passing, powershell-3.0, start-process

I have to install a Exe file silently I only have access to the devices via powershell. The installer will ask for a serial number and path can this be done in PowerShell I have tried below with the silent command removed but it still prompts for the serial number

```
Start-Process -wait DATABASE12.EXE /silent -ArgumentList "ZZZZ-SSS-JJJ-XXXX" 'INSTALLDIR=c:\temp\App'
```

Comment: Try following : $arguments = '/silent ZZZZ-SSS-JJJ-XXXX INSTALLDIR=c:\temp\App' Start-Process DATABASE12.EXE -wait -ArgumentList $arguments

Answer (score 0):

Note: This answer helps you with the *syntax* problem of your own attempt; solving that problem alone doesn't necessarily mean that the command will then work as expected - you'd have to consult the documentation for your specific executable, `DATABASE12.EXE`.

---

Your [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) call is syntactically invalid:

- *All* pass-through arguments, including `/silent`, must be passed via `-ArgumentList` (`-Args`)
- To pass them *individually*, use an *array*, i.e. separate the arguments with `,`

```bash
Start-Process -Wait DATABASE12.EXE -ArgumentList /silent, ZZZZ-SSS-JJJ-XXXX, INSTALLDIR=c:\temp\App
```

However, due to a long-standing bug in `Start-Process` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71271756/45375) - it is usually better to pass all pass-through arguments *encoded in a single string* (separated with *spaces*), which makes it easier to control embedded double-quoting, if necessary:

```bash
# Note: Parameter name -ArgumentList omitted for brevity.
Start-Process -Wait DATABASE12.EXE '/silent ZZZZ-SSS-JJJ-XXXX INSTALLDIR=c:\temp\App'
```