# Open powershell as an administrator and run commands in powershell using bat file

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd, powershell-4.0

I am doing a powershell task manually i.e. opening the powershell **as an administrator** and **executing the command** `pushd D:\PowerShellTry` and command `.\FileWatcher.ps1` in powershell.

I wrote a `myScript.bat` to automate the manual task through a bat file. Below is the code which I wrote for my bat file to automate it:

```
powershell -Command "& {Start-Process powershell.exe -Verb RunAs; pushd D:\PowerShellTry; .\FileWatcher.ps1}"
```

But it is not working. How can I do this correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```bash
powershell -Command "Start-Process -Verb RunAs powershell.exe '-NoExit pushd D:\PowerShellTry; .\FileWatcher.ps1'"
```

Note the use of embedded `'...'` quoting and the `-NoExit` switch to keep the elevated session open, so you can examine the script's output.

As for **what you tried**:

- Note that here's no reason to use `"& { ... }"` in order to invoke code passed to PowerShell's CLI via the `-Command` (`-c`) parameter - just use `"..."` directly, as shown above.
  (Older versions of the [CLI documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh) erroneously suggested that `& { ... }` is required, but this has since been corrected.)
- By placing `;` after [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Start-Process)  `powershell.exe -Verb RunAs`, you terminated the command right there, launching an interactive elevated PowerShell session asynchronously; the subsequent `pushd ...; .\...` commands then executed in the *original*, non-elevated session.

  - Instead, the commands to be run with elevation must be passed *as arguments* to the `powershell.exe` instance launched with `-Verb Runas`, as shown above, just like with the outer `powershell.exe` call (the `-Command` CLI parameter is implied, as is `Start-Process`' `-ArgumentList` parameter).

Comment: I tried to use the above command provided by you. It is not working as per my need. Powershell window is opening but it close automatically. I cannot see if it has executed the 2 certain commands. I also do not want to close the powershell window. Thank you.

Comment: @KumarAnilChaurasiya, you need the `-NoExit` switch to keep the session open. (which is a requirement you didn't mention in your question). Please see my update.

Comment: Thank you. I found another way which does my job -: C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "Start-Process PowerShell -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList '-NoExit', '-Command', 'pushd D:\PowerShellTry";.\FileWatcher.ps1' "

Comment: Your suggestion also works. thanks.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @KumarAnilChaurasiya. There's a stray `"` in your command, after `PowerShellTry`.
I see that you've added additional parameters and spelled out `-ArgumentList`, which is _positionally implied_ in my 
command, for brevity. Also, you've passed _multiple_ arguments to `-ArgumentList`, and while that may be _conceptually_
desirable, a long-standing bug unfortunately makes it better to use a _single_ string that encodes _all_ arguments instead: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71271756/45375).