# Path with spaces considered as multiple paths

Tags: powershell

I have a function for opening things with Notepad++. It works well, except when the passed argument contains spaces. With the entry of OneDrive, I usually get a home directory with the `$PROFILE` like this.

> C:\users\SomeUserName\OneDrive - SomeCompany...\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1*

So, executing my `edit` to edit itself, won't work. The current version looks as below.

```
function Edit {
  param([string]$file = " ")

  $executable = "Notepad++\notepad++.exe"
  $32bit = "C:\Program Files (x86)\" + $executable
  $64bit = "C:\Program Files\" + $executable
  $target = "notepad"

  if(Test-Path $32bit) { $target = $32bit }
  if(Test-Path $64bit) { $target = $64bit }

  Start-Process $target -ArgumentList $file
}
```

I've tried surrounding the `$file` on the last line with quotations marks and parentheses. To no avail, sadly. What more could I try?

As far I understand printing the passed value, it's not an array so flattening it won't do much good. In the future, I may even want to pass multiple files to be opened at once.

Comment: I don't see any issues with your code.  I don't have Notepad++ but I tried it with Notepad and it worked fine when calling it like this [Edit "c:\MyDir With Space\data.txt"] How are you calling it?   Also this is probably a duplicate question of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71271105/in-powershell-spawn-notepad-when-file-to-open-has-spaces-in-it

Comment: @Tolga, it happens to work with Notepad, but it won't work with other editors, and even with Notepad it wouldn't work with _multiple_ paths with embedded spaces. (Notepad, as a debatable courtesy, also accepts `Notepad file with spaces.txt` when  `Notepad "file with spaces.txt"` is intended.) Due to a bug, `Start-Process` neglects to perform this quoting.

Comment: Do not hardcode the program files directory. Use `$Env:ProgramFiles` or `${Env:ProgramFiles(x86)}`. Use `Join-Path`.

Comment: As an aside: You could simplify finding the target executable as follows: `$target = (Get-Command -ErrorActionIgnore $32bit, $64bit, notepad.exe)[0].Path`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>Note: I'm assuming you already know how to properly pass paths with spaces *to* your `Edit` function, i.e. by *enclosing them in quotes*, .e.g. `Edit 'file 2.txt'` or `Edit "file 2.txt"`</sup>

**A [long-standing bug](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5576)<sup>[1]</sup> in [`Start-Process`](https://docs.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) unfortunately requires use of *embedded* double-quoting around arguments that contain spaces**:

```
Start-Process $target -ArgumentList "`"$file`""
```

Note: Remove the default value from your `$file` parameter, i.e. use `param([string] $file)`; if no argument is passed `""` is in effect passed, which most editors ignore.

---

> In the future, I may even want to pass multiple files to be opened at once.

Assuming that parameter `$file` is declared as `param([string[]] $file)`:

```
Start-Process $target -ArgumentList $file.ForEach({ "`"$_`"" })
```

Note:

- The above passes the file paths with embedded quoting as an *array* to `-ArgumentList`, which works well in this case.
  Because of the need for embedded quoting, it is often simpler to pass all arguments encoded in a *single string*, because the situational need to use embedded double-quoting is then obvious - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71271756/45375).
- Declaring the parameter as `string[]] $file` means that on calling your `Edit` function with multiple file paths, you must pass them as a PowerShell array, i.e, `,`-separated (e.g. `Edit file1.txt, 'file 2.txt'`).

  - If you'd rather pass them as *individual arguments* (i.e. *space*-separated; e.g.
    `Edit file1.txt 'file 2.txt'`:

    - Either: Simply use the [automatic `$args` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#args) instead of declaring a `$file` parameter (and then use `` $args.ForEach({ "`"$_`"" }) `` as the `-ArgumentList` argument).
    - Or: Declare your parameter with the `ValueFromRemainingArguments` property:

      ```
      param([Parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments)] [string[]] $file)
      ```

      - Note: Doing so implicitly makes your function an [advanced](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions_Advanced) one.

---

**Taking a step back**:

Since PowerShell invokes GUI-subsystem applications asynchronously *by default*, you don't strictly need `Start-Process` to invoke your editor - just invoke it *directly*, in which case embedded quoting is *not* necessary:

Purely for syntactic reasons, since the executable is specified via a *variable*, you need `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-) to invoke it:<sup>[2]</sup>

```
# Also works if $file is an array.
& $target $file
```

---

<sup>[1] The bug won't be fixed so as not to break backward compatibility, though a *new parameter* may be introduced to work around it.</sup>

<sup>[2] See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57678081/45375) for background information.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

```
function Edit-Files {
<#
.Notes
    bad files are located in the latest tmp file found in $env:TEMP

.Syntax
    Edit-Files
    Edit-Files -Files 'not_exist.txt', 'c:\temp\does exist.txt'

.Links
    https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/command-prompt/
    "For compatibility, Notepad++ will first try to identify the entire command line as a filename, even if it is unquoted. 
    It is however not recommended to do this, as you should always quote the filename."
#>
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)]
    param (
    [Parameter(
        Mandatory=$false
    )]
    [string[]]$files
    )
    begin {
        $os = Get-ComputerInfo -Property OSArchitecture, OsName
        if ($os.OsName -like "*Windows*"){
            if ($os.OsArchitecture -eq '64-bit'){
                $npp = '{0}\notepad++\notepad++.exe' -f $env:ProgramFiles
            } elseif ($os.OsArchitecture -eq '32-bit'){
                $npp = '{0}\notepad++\notepad++.exe' -f ${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}
            } else {
                Write-Warning -Message 'The OsArchitecture is not 32/64-bit.'
            }
        }

        function Select-File {
            begin {
                $collection = [System.Collections.Generic.List[Object]]::new()
            }
            process {
                Do {
                    # display form
                    $dialog = [System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog]@{
                        Filter        = "All Files (*.*)|*.*"
                        FilterIndex   = 1
                        Multiselect   = $true
                        Title         = 'Select file(s)'
                        ValidateNames = $true
                    }
                    $display = $dialog.ShowDialog()

                    # add unique files to collection
                    if ($display -eq 'OK'){
                        $collection.AddRange($dialog.FileNames)
                    }
                } Until ($display -ne 'OK')
                $collection = $collection | Select-Object -Unique | ForEach-Object -Process {Get-Item -LiteralPath $_ -ErrorVariable +badFiles}
                $badFiles | Out-File -LiteralPath (New-TemporaryFile)            
            }
            end {
                $collection
            }
        }
        
        if ($null -eq $PSBoundParameters.Files){
            $files = Select-File
        } else {
            $files = $PSBoundParameters.Files | ForEach-Object -Process {Get-Item -LiteralPath $_ -ErrorVariable +badFiles}
            $badFiles | Out-File -LiteralPath (New-TemporaryFile)
        }
    }
    process {
        foreach ($singleFile in $files){
            if ($PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess($singleFile, "Edit")){

                # option 1
                # & $npp --help
                & $npp $singleFile

                # option 2
                #Start-Process -FilePath $npp -ArgumentList ('"{0}"' -f $singleFile)
            }
        }
    } end {

    }
}
```

Comment: While your (lengthy) code may or may not be helpful, posting it without an explanation and how it relates to question is unlikely to make your answer useful to future readers.

Comment: @mklement0 I, as the OP, can tell you that one of your "may's" is superfluous. While maintaining polite and kind tone towards the new user's attempt, I sense that it's ChatGPT generated answer. It kinds of talks about the issue but misses the point.   :)

Comment: @KonradViltersten I appreciate both of your comments but I added what I believed the reasoning was in the comment block under '.Links' and came up with the same solution regarding files containing spaces. I'll keep in mind to leave my answer outside of the code block. That being said the correct answer was provided by mklement0 with the reference to the long-standing bug. Additionally, I can assure you it is not a ChatGPT generated answer. it was partially aggregated from other sources, but it was originally intended for my job. The code is lengthy because I updated your function.

Comment: Then my sensation is flawed, which I apologize for. No insult intended. As for the answer, I agree that the explanatory text shouldn't be a part of the code. I'll gladly upvote your answer if you can go through the effort of splitting it up, describing etc. It'll help others in the future as well.