# Why does Powershell Start-Process cmdlet handle argument arrays differently than Invocation Operator

Tags: powershell

I have been attempting to automate some processes via powershell script and have been running into problems launching one specific external executable, it would only work when launched using the Start-Process cmdlet and it would give me an error message saying that it did not recognize the command line arguments when launched using the invocation operator (&).  After much profane language was expended in this tool's direction I ascertained that the way the invocation operator handles argument arrays was tripping up the tool's cmd argument parsing (and sadly it is an external tool so I can't fix it).  Example is as follows

I wrote a small C# cmd line program that simply echos the cmd arguments it is given

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Arg Echo");
    foreach (string arg in args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(arg);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("End");
}
```

This is the output when the executable is launched directly from the windows cmd prompt

```
>CmdArgsEcho.exe /Arg1 "Val1" /Arg2 Val2
Arg Echo
/Arg1
Val1
/Arg2
Val2
End
```

I wrote the following script to illustrate what I'm talking about

```
$Exe = "$PSScriptRoot/CmdArgsEcho.exe"

$Value1 = "`"Val1`""
$Value2 = "Val2"

$Args = @("/Arg1 $Value1", "/Arg2 $Value2")
$Args2 = @("/Arg1", "$Value1", "/Arg2", "$Value2")

'Launch via Start-Process'
Start-Process -FilePath $Exe -ArgumentList $Args -NoNewWindow -Wait
' '
'Launch via Invocation Operator'
& $Exe $Args
' '
'Launch via Invocation Operator With Args2'
& $Exe $Args2
```

This is the output of the script (In Powershell7)

```
Launch via Start-Process
Arg Echo
/Arg1
Val1
/Arg2
Val2
End

Launch via Invocation Operator
Arg Echo
/Arg1 "Val1"
/Arg2 Val2
End

Launch via Invocation Operator With Args2
Arg Echo
/Arg1
"Val1"
/Arg2
Val2
End
```

You'll notice that when launched via Start-Process the arguments and values are separated on to their own lines the same way that they were when launching directly via windows cmd prompt, but when launched via invocation operator each element of the args array stays together as one argument in the called executable.  Is this the way that argument arrays are supposed to work with the invocation operator?  The examples of this that I've found all set up the arguments and values in one array which is why I was trying to do it like that.  Is there a better/idiomatic way of handling arguments and values when using the invocation operator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr**

- Direct invocation (possibly via `&`) *mostly* works as intended, but you must pass tokens *individually*, which means passing a parameter *name* in a separate element from *its value*, but without *embedded* quoting.
- `Start-Process` may happen to do what you want *in your case*, but its behavior is fundamentally broken.

---

###### The behavior of direct invocation, including via `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-):

If you're using an *array* to pass arguments to an *external program*, you must pass tokens *individually*, which means passing a parameter *name* in a separate element from *its value*.

Therefore, your `$Args2` definition is the right approach in principle, but you do *not* need *embedded* quoting in your values:

```bash
$Value1 = 'Val 1'  # value with spaces
$Value2 = "Val2"

$Args2 = @("/Arg1", $Value1, "/Arg2", $Value2)

& $Exe $Args2 # OK
```

PowerShell *automatically* encloses any tokens that contain *spaces* in `"..."` when it constructs the *process command line* behind the scenes that is used for actual invocation on Windows. Conversely, irrespective of what quoting was originally used in *PowerShell* code, a space-less argument is used *unquoted*.

In the example above, this process command line looks something like:

```bash
C:\path\to\CmdArgsEcho.exe /Arg1 "Val 1" Val2
```

The **passing of argument values with *embedded* `"` characters is actually *broken* in *Windows PowerShell* and in [PowerShell (Core)](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)  *up to v7.2.x*** in that they're *not escaped as* `\"`, as they should be (given that direct invocation - in the absence of `--%` is *not* meant to be way to control the process command line explicitly). The problem is **fixed in v7.3+**, but by default with **selective exceptions on Windows** - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74440425/45375).

---

###### The behavior of `Start-Process`

You're seeing **a *long-standing bug*** in [`Start-Process`](https://docs.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process), originally reported in [GitHub issue #5576](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5576):

- If multiple arguments are passed to `-ArgumentList`, they are *blindly joined with spaces* for inclusion on the process command line - even if they *individually* contain spaces - as a result, argument boundaries are lost.

  - Note that `Start-Process` does *not* see whatever quoting you may have used on *PowerShell*'s command line; e.g, `` -ArgumentList foo` bar, "foo bar", 'foo bar' `` results in an array whose three elements all contain verbatim value `foo bar`, and it is those verbatim values that are joined as-is to form part of the *process* command line that is formed behind the scenes on Windows.
  - It is the C# runtime that parses this process command line for you and reports the resulting array of verbatim tokens as `string[] args` in your `Main` method.

    - The runtime uses the [C++ rules](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/main-function-command-line-args#parsing-c-command-line-arguments) for parsing, which, in a nutshell, means:

      - arguments with embedded spaces must be enclosed in `"..."`
      - `"` chars. meant to be a verbatim part of an argument must escaped as `\"`
      - A `\` char. meant to be verbatim must escaped as `\\` *if it is immediately followed by `"`*.
- So as not to break existing *workarounds* - namely using *embedded* quoting in array elements with spaces - this bug *will not be fixed*.

  - However, introduction of a *new* parameter is being discussed in the linked GitHub issue - this hasn't yet happened as of PowerShell 7.3.10 (the version current as of this writing).

For now, the best **workaround** is to pass a *single* string in which *all* arguments are encoded - e.g. `-ArgumentList '-foo "bar baz"'` rather than `-ArgumentList '-foo', '"bar baz"'` - because the situational need to use *embedded* double-quoting is then obvious.
See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71271756/45375) for details.