# How to set default location to start in profile.ps1?

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I have the following line on my `D:\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1` profile file:

```
Set-Location $env:HOMEDRIVE
```

Worth noting that `$env:HOMEDRIVE` equals to `C:`. The expected behavior is that whenever I open a PS shell I would be put in `C:`, but that's not what I'm getting, instead I get placed in `$env:HOMEPATH`, which equals to `C:\Users\<my username here>`.

Why this behavior and how to "fix"?

---

Info regarding my PS version:

```
PS C:\Users\...> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.14393.2068
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.14393.2068
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

Comment: I am unable to reproduce it on PS 5.1.15063.909

Comment: Why not use `cd c:\ ` ?

Comment: @gms0ulman because (1) I want something scalable, `C:` is not the `HOMEDRIVE` in all my systems, this `profile.ps1` is used on many systems at home and at work, even if all of them were `C:` I'd never use static paths in any code, this is just bad practice; and (2) I want to use PS syntax, `cd` is nothing more than an alias to `Set-Location`. Anyway, I tried with `cd C:` and didn't work...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting the location to a drive letter with no path (ie. `C:`) just switches to the location stack of that drive, it doesn't actually change the path. Change it to:

```
Set-Location (Join-Path $env:HOMEDRIVE '\')
```

Answer (score 1):

To test. I put this in my `profile.ps1`:

```
Set-Location $env:HOMEDRIVE
Write-Host $env:HOMEDRIVE
```

**Output**

```
C:
PS C:\Users\<my username>>
```

**Resolution**

```
Set-Location "$($env:HOMEDRIVE)\"
Write-Host $env:HOMEDRIVE
```

**Output**

```
C:
PS C:\>
```

Answer (score 1):

To *complement* [Mathias R. Jessen's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48846470/45375) with **background information**:

PowerShell's

```
Set-Location $env:HOMEDRIVE
```

is equivalent to `cmd.exe`'s:

```
cd /d %HOMEDRIVE%
```

- That is, the reference to environment variable `HOMEDRIVE` is replaced with its value (expanded) - typically `C:` - and that *drive* is *changed to*. Note how PowerShell does *not* require an analog to the `/d` switch to make the drive change take effect.
- However, in both shells, **changing to a *drive spec. only* - without a path component - changes to *whatever the shell considers the current directory* on that drive**, which may or may not be the root directory.

  - In order to **change to a specific directory** - such as the root directory - **its path must be specified too**.

While `Set-Location (Join-Path $env:HOMEDRIVE '\')` is a robust and generic way to construct and **pass the path to the root directory** of the drive spec. stored in environment variable `HOMEDRIVE`, PowerShell offers a **more concise alternative**:

```
Set-Location $env:HOMEDRIVE\ # or, with variable name disambiguated: ${env:HOMEDRIVE}\
```

The above works, because, simply put, PowerShell parses string arguments implicitly as if they were *expandable strings* (double-quoted strings with embedded variable references or even commands).

That is, the above is equivalent to all of the following:

```
Set-Location "$env:HOMEDRIVE\"      # expandable string
Set-Location "${env:HOMEDRIVE}\"    # ditto, variable name disambiguated
Set-Location "$(${env:HOMEDRIVE})\" # $(...) embeds full commands (not necessary here)
```

In addition to `Join-Path` being a more robust way to join path components, there are **pitfalls** associated **with the unquoted-argument approach**, such as subtle differences between unquoted and double-quoted arguments (interior whitespace *requires* double-quoting, as do certain characters that are shell metacharacters); when in doubt, pass the argument to `Write-Output` to see what it expands to; for details, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41254359/45375) of mine.