# How to pass cmdlet output as an argument to an application (.exe) without an intermediate variable?

Tags: powershell

I have the following PS command that returns a string:

```
(get-date -Uformat %s).remove(10, 1).substring(5,9)
```

I want to call the application `myapp.exe` from the current directory with the result of that PS command as an argument, and I want to do it in a single line (no intermediate variable). What's the syntax for that?

In other words, I'm looking for a Powershell equivalent for `$(<command>)` in bash.

Comment: Just... do?  Try it and find out.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1: do what? I've been googling for it for at least 15 minutes, no luck.

Comment: I meant try what you have: myapp.exe <expression>.  This isn't a question, it's a statement because you haven't tried anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
./myapp.exe (get-date -Uformat %s).remove(10, 1).substring(5,9)
```

- `./myapp.exe` (or `.\myapp.exe`) invokes executable `myapp.exe` located in the current directory.

  - If `myapp.exe` is instead located in a directory listed in `$env:PATH`, do *not* use the `./` \ `.\` prefix.
  - Either way, the resulting process *runs* in the current directory (filesystem-provider location).
- Arguments passed to executables are (fittingly) parsed in *argument mode* (see [`Get-Help about_Parsing`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing)) and how a given (whitespace-separated) argument is interpreted depends on its *first character*:

  - Since the first character is `(`, the argument is evaluated as an *expression* (parsed in *expression mode*); whatever that expression evaluates to is passed to the the executable.
    The other special characters in the first position are `$`, `@`, as well as  `'`, and `"` (see next point).

    - Note that while `$(...)` - the *subexpression operator* (see [`Get-Help about_Operators`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators)) - would *also* work in this case, it is overkill if only a *single* expression (`(...)`) is to be evaluated - `$(...)` is only needed if you want to pass the output from *multiple statements*.
  - The content of a `'...'` argument (single-quoted) is treated as a *literal*, whereas the content of a `"..."` argument is an *expandable string* (loosely speaking, a string in which `$`-prefixed tokens are interpolated).
  - Any other argument (one that is unquoted and doesn't start with `(`, `@`, or `$`), by and large, is *implicitly* treated like an expandable string, i.e., as if you had enclosed it in `"..."`.
  - For a comprehensive overview of how arguments that aren't explicitly enclosed in `"..."` or `'...'` are parsed in argument mode, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41254359/45375) of mine.

    - For potentially surprising behavior in this context, see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6467).

Answer (score 1):

i think you are looking for this:

```
command ((get-date -Uformat %s).remove(10, 1).substring(5,9))
```

but your command should work even without `()`

Comment: Adding another set of parenthesis is unnecessary.  His current example will work as it is.

Comment: yeah, but in general it is, although I agree with you and added that to the answer

Comment: Only when you're using the output of a command as an expression (like `if (-not (Test-Path -Path .)) {`

Comment: `get-process ('{0}host' -f 'svc')`

Comment: `'<string>' -f $array` **is an expression**.

Comment: Wow. I swear this is very difficult to find any documentation for or mentions of (possibly because everyone knows this already). Thanks.

Comment: isnt everything an expression, technically? @TheIncorrigible1

Comment: An object isn't an expression.  Expressions have outputs

Comment: you'd need to use an expression to get an object, right? xD

Comment: Unless you're using a literal, yes.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe A lot of programming is just trying something and seeing if it works then figuring out how it works later.  [I suggest reading this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing?view=powershell-5.1)

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1: Thank you. I thought myself a respectable professional programmer out of age when I used to mash keys like a monkey hoping to find a solution by luck, without having at least a remote idea what _must_ work eventually. Guess it's still a legitimate method of learning, ha-ha.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe We're all forever learning in this field :) On a serious note: Microsoft has EXCELLENT documentation on powershell & all its behaviors.  I'd check out the `Get-Help about_*` topics if you find yourself stuck on something engine-wide (not just a single cmdlet)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Invoke-Expression`, however, keep in mind that there are security considerations to ponder when using this cmdlet, as it may open you up to code-injection attacks. Also note that `Invoke-Expression` will usually succeed even when the underlying command fails with an error.

```
$command = "myapp.exe '$((get-date -Uformat %s).remove(10, 1).substring(5,9))'"
Invoke-Expression $command
```

If you want to check the success of your command, check `$LASTEXITCODE` for a suitable exitcode and continue/fail based on that. Note that `$LASTEXITCODE` only works when checking the result of a program, not a cmdlet.

## Avoiding `Invoke-Expression`

You can avoid the use of `Invoke-Expression` by building an array of arguments to pass to your command line application, like so (in your case, it would just be one argument but this can be expanded to build out more complex commands with more than one argument as well, just add additional array elements for each switch, parameter, or value):

```
$cmdargs = @(
  ( GetDdate -Uformat %s ).Remove( 10, 1 ).Substring( 5,9 )
)
myapp.exe $cmdargs
```

You can still track success of the command by checking the value of `$LASTEXITCODE`.

## Keeping it simple

In your case, you can just call `myapp.exe (get-date -Uformat %s).remove(10, 1).substring(5,9)` which will insert the date string as an argument. But the above techniques (building an array is the preferred method to `Invoke-Expression`) becomes useful when you want to build a more complex command based on a number of conditions.

Comment: There is rarely a good reason to use `Invoke-Expression`; it should be avoided, because more robust solutions are usually available (as is the case here) and because - due to its ability to invoke arbitrary commands passed as strings - it can be a security risk, as you state. Avoiding it unless absolutely necessary is a good habit to form. Here, the target expression can simply be passed as-is to the the target executable (`myapp.exe (get-date ...)`).

Comment: For programs, you *can* build a string and execute them with `& $command`. But for cmdlets, I don't know of a better way to conditionally build a command out than build a string and call it with `Invoke-Expression`.

Comment: `&` can be used with cmdlet/function/script names [in quoted strings / stored in variables] too. Try  `& Get-Date`, `$cmd = 'Get-Date'; & $cmd`, `& 'Get-Date'`. Do note that only the _command name / file path_ is the argument to `&`, whereas the _arguments_ are   passed separately, as usual.

Comment: I did not know that, I thought `&` was specifically for program execution. Learn something new every day.

Comment: Glad to hear it. All _commands_ (cmdlets, functions, scripts, external programs, aliases, script blocks) are created equal with respect to `&` (and `.`), and, with the exception of script blocks, with respect to direct invocation. Recommending `Invoke-Expression` in this scenario is a bad idea in my opinion, so please consider revising your answer.

Comment: I disagree, if only *because* it it's a common, yet insecure solution to this problem. The answer is valid *and* outlines the security implication. Though I may add to the answer later with an alternative solution as well, if I get the time tonight.

Comment: Perhaps it is common, but it is ill-advised. Yes, you mention the security implications, but the point is that for the scenario at hand there's no good reason to  bring `Invoke-Expression` into the conversion to begin with - except in order to advise against its use.

Comment: Finally got around to adding an alternative solution. I left the `Invoke-Expression` bit to serve as a warning.

Comment: I appreciate the effort, but from the perspective of the question asked - how to pass an expression as an argument to a directly invoked console program - the structure of your answer is backward: The _last_ approach (covered by the other answers) should go first, _then_ it's worth mentioning use of an _array_; again, no good reason to even mention `Invoke-Expression`, except to say [that it is considered harmful](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/).

Comment: Well you are always free to write your own answer. Can't please everyone.

Comment: That's true. I wrote my own answer 2 days ago (and it is - as of this writing - the accepted one). That is not mutually exclusive with suggesting improvements to other answers, especially if they have the potential to be a useful _complement_ to the accepted answer.