# How do I run a command using the output of another function in powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have the following, perfectly working `ps1` script:

```
function Get-ScriptDirectory {
    $Invocation = (Get-Variable MyInvocation -Scope 1).Value
    Split-Path $Invocation.MyCommand.Path
}

$currentDir = Get-ScriptDirectory

node $currentDir/yarn.js $args
```

I would like to eliminate the `$currentDir` variable. I am trying to run:

```
function Get-ScriptDirectory {
    $Invocation = (Get-Variable MyInvocation -Scope 1).Value
    Split-Path $Invocation.MyCommand.Path
}

node (Get-ScriptDirectory)/yarn.js $args
```

But this fails - it looks like `Get-ScriptDirectory` output becomes the first argument. I've tried using quotes, and that doesn't work either - the brackets no longer expand.

**How do I run a command using the output of a function?**

Comment: @PetSerAl Thanks! Whats the difference between `$()` and `()` anyway? Add it as an answer and I'll mark it correct.

Comment: Blog that explains [using subexpressions within strings](https://www.pdq.com/blog/using-subexpressions-within-strings/) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>Based on past experience, there's no point in waiting for [PetSerAl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4003407/petseral) to post an answer, though his pointers are always appreciated.</sup>

Your **options** are:

- Either: Use an *expression* to construct the path:

  ```
  node  ((Get-ScriptDirectory) + '/yarn.js') $Args
  ```
- Or: Use an *expandable string* (string interpolation):

  ```
  node  "$(Get-ScriptDirectory)/yarn.js" $Args
  ```

---

**Background**:

- `(...)` is required to enclose a single expression or command in a context where a *command argument* or *subexpression* is expected (which could be a *command* invocation that itself needs to be wrapped in `(...)` or an embedded expression whose evaluation precedence needed clarification).
- `$(...)`is the - more flexible, but slower - subexpression operator:

  - In order to embed an expression or command(s) in an *expandable string* (`"..."`), you *must* use `$(...)` - `(...)` wont' work.
  - *Outside* of an expandable string, while `$(...)` generally *also* works, there's generally no need to use it, unless you need to execute *multiple* statements.

    - For a single expression / command, `(...)` is not only sufficient but *performs better*.

---

**Additional information**:

- To learn about **PowerShell's fundamental parsing modes**, see [`Get-Help about_Parsing`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing)
- To learn about **PowerShell's string expansion (string interpolation) rules**, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375) of mine.
- For a comprehensive discussion of **how unquoted command-line tokens are parsed in argument mode (as command arguments)**, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41254359/45375) of mine.