# $openfiledialog1 and Set-Content or Out-File how to do that? Passing a file-path argument composed of multiple variable and property references

Tags: powershell, syntax, parameter-passing

SOLUTION on the bottom .

I find my self how to use

```
($openfiledialog1.ShowDialog() -eq 'OK')
{
    $textboxFile.Text = $openfiledialog1.FileName
}
```

I can extract and change the text inside of this file and save at the same path.

I would like to save in another place and I tried some thing

```
(Get-Content $textboxFile.Text).Replace('$Name', 'test') |
    Out-File $HOME\$openfiledialog1.SafeFileNames
```

I tried with `Set-Content` same issue, the script can't save and error appear.

```
ERROR: Set-Content : Could not open the alternate data stream ' Title: , FileName: C:\Users\Administrator.SERVERAD\Documents\test.txt' of the file
ERROR: 'C:\Users\Administrator.SERVERADSystem.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog'. MainForm.psf (24, 59):
ERROR: At Line: 24 char: 59
ERROR: + ... xt).replace('$Name', 'test')|Set-Content -Path $HOME\$openfiledialog1
```

The final usage is change some data inside of HTML file.

Ansgar I don't understand your solution but you keep me on the good way thank you so much.
After 2 hours and some break I find a SOLUTION, but I don't why I can't use directly `$openfiledialog1.SafeFileName`.

```
$buttonBrowse_Click = {
    if ($openfiledialog1.ShowDialog() -eq 'OK') {
        $textboxFile.Text = $openfiledialog1.SafeFileName
    }
}

$button1_Click = {
    $b = $textboxFile.Text 
    # also this things work too $b=$openfiledialog1.SafeFileName
    # TODO: Place custom script here
    (Get-Content $openfiledialog1.FileName).replace('$Name', "text") |
        Out-File $HOME\$b
}
```

Comment: Split your action into 3 individual steps (read, replace, write). Which of them is throwing the error, and what does the error say exactly?

Comment: This error ,I thing the script try to change the tittle .
ERROR: Set-Content : Could not open the alternate data stream ' Title: , FileName: C:\Users\Administrator.SERVERAD\Documents\test.txt' of the file
ERROR: 'C:\Users\Administrator.SERVERAD\System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog'.
MainForm.psf (24, 59): ERROR: At Line: 24 char: 59
ERROR: + ... xt).replace('$Name', 'test')|Set-Content -Path $HOME\$openfiledialog1

Comment: this ligne work  `(Get-Content $openfiledialog1.filename).replace('$Name','test')|Set-Content $openfiledialog1.filename` but is the same path .

Comment: Ansgar if i understood ,I extract the text in variable and then I can do use `replace` and then I can save ?
i will try .

Comment: Please [edit] your question. Do not bury this information in comments. Also, please remove the custom error formatting from your script, so that we can see the actual error message.

Comment: Something about `$HOME` or `$openfiledialog1.SafeFileNames` is not right. Check both values. Also try something like `$filename = $openfiledialog1.SafeFileNames; ... | Set-Content "$HOME\$filename"`.

Comment: if i use  `(Get-Content $openfiledialog1.filename).replace('$Name', 'test')|Out-File $HOME\text.txt` that's perflectly fine .My issue is not totally solved because If I want to change lot of file .I am limited .I will try your option .

Comment: Thank ansgar for your help .I find a solution .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr**

In order to reference property value `$openfiledialog1.SafeFileName` as part of the file-path argument, you must enclose it in `$(...)`:

```
... | Out-File "$HOME\$($openfiledialog1.SafeFileName)" # Note the $(...)
```

<sup>You could omit the enclosing `"`, but I suggest using them for conceptual clarity and general robustness.</sup>

---

As for **what you tried**:

`$HOME\$openfiledialog1.SafeFileNames` isn't expanded the way you expect:

`.SafeFileNames` is treated as a *literal*, meaning that `$openfiledialog1` *by itself* is expanded, which is not your intent.

Here's a simple example:

```
PS> Write-Output $HOME\$PSVersionTable.PSVersion
C:\Users\jdoe\System.Management.Automation.PSVersionHashTable.PSVersion
```

You may have expected something like `C:\Users\jdoe\5.1.16299.492`, but as you can see, `.PSVersion` was retained as a literal, and `$PSVersionTable` *by itself* was stringified, which resulted in the (unhelpful) `System.Management.Automation.PSVersionHashTable` representation.

The reason for this behavior is that **an unquoted token such as `$HOME\$openfiledialog1.SafeFileName` is treated much like an *expandable string***, i.e. like a token enclosed in `"..."`.

Inside `"..."`, only *mere variable references* can be embedded as-is (e.g., `"Value: $var"`); by contrast, **accessing a variable's *property* is an *expression* that must be enclosed in `$(...)`**, i.e. a call to the *subexpression operator* (e.g., `"Value: $($var.Foo)"`)

For an overview of *string-expansion rules*, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375) of mine.

For an overview of *how unquoted tokens are parsed as command arguments*, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41254359/45375) of mine.