# Powershell get path value from xml file

Tags: powershell

I'm a beginner of powershell and I'm having trouble reading the path value of an xml file.

Settings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <Configuration>
   <EmailSettings>
    <SMTPServer>blabla</SMTPServer>
    <SMTPPort>blabla</SMTPPort>
    <Path>Repository\Excel</Path>   
  </EmailSettings>
 </Configuration>
```

To read the data in the XML file I do this way

```
$ScriptPath = Split-Path -Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition -Parent

[xml]$ConfigFile = Get-Content "$ScriptPath\Settings.xml"
```

The problem is that if I display the extracted value it is shown correctly, while if I concatenate it with another value, for example to obtain a complete path, I get this

```
Write-Host $ScriptPath  
--> c:\script

write-host $ConfigFile.Configuration.EmailSettings.Path 
--> Repository\Excel

write-host $ScriptPath\$ConfigFile.Configuration.EmailSettings.Path   
--> c:\script\System.Xml.XmlDocument.Configuration.EmailSettings.Path
```

How do we do to get the value (in string format??) to be able to concatenate to other variables?

Thank you

Comment: You are already using `Split-Path` to get a part into a variable, well what about `Join-Path`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You need `$(...)`, the subexpression operator**, in order to evaluate an *expression* such as `$ConfigFile.Configuration.EmailSettings.Path` inside an *expandable string*.
By contrast, a *simple variable reference* such as `$ScriptPath` is fine without the `$(...)`:

```
Write-Host "$ScriptPath\$($ConfigFile.Configuration.EmailSettings.Path)"
```

Note that I've additionally added explicit double-quoting, to make the command more robust - see below for details.

As an aside: [`Write-Host` is generally the wrong tool to use](http://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful/), unless the intent is explicitly to write to the display only, bypassing PowerShell's output streams.

---

Generally, ***unquoted* tokens that aren't single expressions are *implicitly* treated like expandable strings**, i.e., as if they had been passed in double quotes, and by and large [the same rules apply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375).

However, in the absence of explicit quoting there are additional pitfalls, such as tokens that start with `-` or the need to escape additional characters, so ***always* double-quoting expandable tokens is a good habit to form.**

How PowerShell parses unquoted tokens in argument mode in general is a complex topic - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41254359/45375).

Comment: My pleasure, @Gus; glad to hear it was helpful.