# How can I pass a TimeSpan argument to a script?

Tags: powershell

I'm new to powershell and have only used script parameters of type string yet. Now I try to create a script which deletes backups which are older than a given time span, similar to this one:

```
Param(
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string] $BackupFolder,
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [Timespan] $StorageDuration
)
$BackupFolder | ls -ad |? { (New-TimeSpan -Start $_.CreationTime -End Get-Date) -ge $StorageDuration} |% {$_|rm -Confirm:$false -Recurse}
```

Is there a way for a caller **from the PS command line** to pass a time span argument like e.g. 'New-TimeSpan -Days 7' ?
I made a workaround where only the days are passed as an argument but I don't like this limitation and would prefer to pass the whole time span as a single parameter, possibly including days, minutes, hours and so on.

There are also two minor issues in my script which I don't understand. Maybe you can also answer these to help me improving my powershell knowledge:

1. [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-6#parameters) says that d and ad are aliases for the Directory parameter. But when I use d instead of ad, I receive an error message saying that no argument for the parameter depth was specified. Did they mix something up there?
2. Why do I have to write a colon between -Confirm and $false? When I omit that, it tells me that no positional parameter takes the value false.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- To pass a `[timespan]` value as an *argument* - or, indeed, *any* expression - enclose it in `(...)`.
  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41254359/45375) for how PowerShell parses command arguments.

  ```
  # Pass a [timespan] to cmdlet Get-Foo
  Get-Foo (New-TimeSpan -Days 7)
  ```
- `-d` not being accepted as an alias of `-Directory` is a *bug*:

  - `-d` is mistakenly interpreted as the prefix form of the `-Depth` parameter, even though `-d` is explicitly declared as an alias of `-Directory` (as is `-ad`).
  - The proper behavior is for parameter aliases to *always* be accepted as-is - even if their name happens to be a prefix of a *different* parameter (such as `-Depth` in this case).

    - As an aside: If the `-d` alias *didn't* exist, PowerShell would normally sensibly report a `parameter name 'd' is ambiguous` error, because the name prefix specified is not long enough to uniquely identify the target parameter.<sup>[1]</sup>
  - See [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4739).
- `-Confirm` is a *switch* parameter, which normally doesn't take an *argument*: (with exceptions<sup>[2]</sup>) it is a switch's *absence or presence* that determines its value.

  - Because switch parameters don't take an argument, whatever token follows them is considered the *next* argument.
  - Therefore, you must use `:` after the switch name to tell PowerShell that the following token is the *switch*'s argument.

    - As an aside: the `:` syntax works even with non-switch parameters, i.e. those that always require an argument, but it is rarely used in that case.

---

<sup>[1] PowerShell generally allows you to use only the *prefix* of a parameter name as long as that prefix is unique among all parameters supported by a given command. The ability to take such shortcuts is what PowerShell calls ***elastic syntax***, and it is **intended for *interactive* use** (on the command line). You should **avoid elastic syntax in *scripts***, because such scripts may break in the future, if a command introduces a *new* parameter that makes a previously unique name prefix no longer unique.</sup>

<sup>[2] Your use case, `-Confirm:$false` shows one such exception: it signals the explicit intent not to ask for confirmation, which is *not* the same as *omitting* the `-Confirm` switch: the former *unconditionally* opts out of prompting, whereas the latter makes the behavior dependent on the target command's declared impact level and the current value of the `$ConfirmPreference` preference variable.</sup>