# Using .NET framework namespaces and classes

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

I would like to use a .NET Framework class inside a PowerShell script. I've searched and read that it should be possible. What I have tried is the following:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Resources
$resx = New-Object [System.Resources.ResXResourceWriter];
```

But doing so throws an exception:

```
New-Object : Cannot find type [[System.Resources.ResXResourceWriter]]: verify
that the assembly containing this type is loaded.
At C:\temp\Translation\import_translation.ps1:41 char:25
+ ...             $resx = New-Object [System.Resources.ResXResourceWriter];
+                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidType: (:) [New-Object], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
```

The assembly does not appear to be found, even though I'm loading it using the `Add-Type` command above. How can I use .NET Framework classes in PowerShell?

Comment: Aside from the primary problem of including the enclosing `[...]` in the `New-Object` call, there are two additional problems: (a) The type of interest is in the `System.Windows.Forms` assembly (`Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms`), and (b) the type of interest doesn't have a _parameter-less_ constructor.

Comment: I'm also curious why `Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Resources` didn't result in an error, given that no such assembly is normally in the GAC.

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr**:

<sup>Note: In addition to the primary problem shown below, there are **two additional problems**:

* It is the `System.Windows.Forms.dll` assembly that contains the type of interest, so the `Add-Type` command should be: `Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms`; add `-Passthru` to see what types are being loaded.

* Type `[System.Resources.ResXResourceWriter]` does not have a *parameter-less* constructor; run `[System.Resources.ResXResourceWriter]::new` (without `()`) to see the available constructor overloads; see bottom section.</sup>

Your **primary problem**:

Instead of:

```
$resx = New-Object [System.Resources.ResXResourceWriter] # WRONG, due to [...]
```

use:

```
$resx = New-Object System.Resources.ResXResourceWriter  # OK - no [...]
```

Alternatively, in PSv5+:

```
$resx = [System.Resources.ResXResourceWriter]::new() # OK
```

---

When you pass `[System.Resources.ResXResourceWriter]` as an *argument* to a command, it is treated *verbatim*, not as a *type literal* - and a type whose full name is *literally* `[System.Resources.ResXResourceWriter]`, *with* the enclosing `[` and `]`, doesn't exist.

The reason is that command arguments are parsed in [*argument mode*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing), where `[` has no special meaning as the 1st char. of an argument.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41254359/45375) for an overview of how (unquoted) tokens are parsed in argument mode.

While you can force a token to be interpreted as an *expression* by enclosing it in `(...)` - `([System.Resources.ResXResourceWriter])`, in this case - that just creates extra work, because the type literal is converted back to a *string* when the value is bound to the `New-Object`'s `-TypeName` parameter.

PowerShell v5 introduced the static `::new()` method that you can call on type literals in *expression mode* in order to invoke constructors with the *method syntax*, analogous to how you call methods in C#, as shown above.

Calling `::new` *without `()`* is also a convenient way to list the available constructor overloads, i.e. to see what constructor variants with what parameters the type supports; e.g.:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Resources.ResXResourceWriter]::new
```

yields:

```
OverloadDefinitions
-------------------
System.Resources.ResXResourceWriter new(string fileName)
System.Resources.ResXResourceWriter new(string fileName, System.Func[type,string] typeNameConverter)
System.Resources.ResXResourceWriter new(System.IO.Stream stream)
System.Resources.ResXResourceWriter new(System.IO.Stream stream, System.Func[type,string] typeNameConverter)
System.Resources.ResXResourceWriter new(System.IO.TextWriter textWriter)
System.Resources.ResXResourceWriter new(System.IO.TextWriter textWriter, System.Func[type,string] typeNameConverter)
```

For instance, to call the 2nd overload from the list above, you'd using something like (using bogus arguments):

```
[System.Resources.ResXResourceWriter]::new('c:\tmp\foo', {})
```

Comment: @developer82: Using the usual method syntax, similar to C#; please see my update.

Comment: Do that returns a null object while using `New-Object` returns an object

Comment: @developer82: No, both `New-Object` and `::new()` return the newly constructed instance; try `Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms; [System.Resources.ResXResourceWriter]::new('c:\tmp\foo', {}).GetType().FullName`