# Calling a function variably

Tags: .net, powershell

I have several PS1s with functions in them in the format "Invoke-T1234", "Invoke-T1235", etc.
I'd like to create a function in a PS Module that allows the user to call one of these PS1s through an argument, e.g. "Invoke-Script -Script T1234" and it then runs "Invoke-T1234". Is it possible to pass in a variable to the function that calls the scripts so I don't have to create several "If" clauses?

E.g.

```
function Invoke-Script {
        param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]       
            [string]$Script= ""
        )
    If ($Script){
    Invoke-$Script    
    }
```

Obviously this isn't working, as PowerShell is interpreting $Script literally instead of the value.

I know I can do

```
If ($Script -eq T1234){
Invoke-T1234}
```

But there are many PS1s, so I'd like to do this in the least amount of code possible.

Comment: Try `invoke-Expression "Invoke-$Script"`. It also may help to provide the full path

Comment: @AbrahamZinala [`Invoke-Expression`  (`iex`) should generally be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51252636/45375); definitely [don't use it to invoke an external program or PowerShell script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57966347/45375). The simpler and safer alternative here is to use `& "Invoke-$Script"`

Answer (score 2):

You could use `Get-Command` to discover the target function based on the argument:

```
function Invoke-TScript
{
  param(
    [int]$ScriptID
  )

  $cmd = Get-Command "Invoke-T${ScriptID}" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
  if($cmd){
    & $cmd @args
  }
  else {
    Write-Error "No function named 'Invoke-T${ScriptID}' available"
  }
}
```

Splatting the automatic `$args` variable inside the function means any additional parameter arguments will be passed to the target script.

Now you can do:

```
Invoke-TScript -ScriptID 1234 -ScriptParam 'script argument'
```

which will then execute:

```
Invoke-T1234 -ScriptParam 'script argument'
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [`Get-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-command) to discover and test the existence of commands, as shown in [Mathias R. Jessen's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69481151/45375), is definitely an option, but if you know the specific name of the command (function), as in your case, it is sufficient to **use `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-)**, which **can invoke commands specified via a(n expandable) *string*,  *variable* or *expression***:

```sh
# Use an expandable string to construct the target command name
# and invoke it with &
# If needed, pass arguments as you usually would; e.g.
#   & "Invoke-$Script" foo bar
& "Invoke-$Script"
```

- You don't even strictly need quoting (the enclosing `"..."`) here: `& Invoke-$Script` will do.

  - Because the arguments passed to `&` are parsed in [argument(-parsing) mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Parsing#argument-mode), PowerShell generally treats unquoted arguments that include variable references (such as `Invoke-$Script`) *implicitly* like an [expandable string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375), i.e. *as if they had explicitly been enclosed in `"..."`*. However, there are *pitfalls*, so it's a good habit to form to use `"..."` explicitly - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58809351/45375) for background information.
- Conversely, when quoting *is* used, use of `&` is *required*, even with *verbatim* strings, whereas *unquoted, verbatim* command names and paths do *not* require `&` (but may be used with it); e.g. `c:\foo\script.ps1` works without `&` too, but
  `& 'c:\foo\script file.ps1'` requires `&`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57678081/45375) for background information.

In the context of your code, with an error handler:

```sh
function Invoke-Script {
        param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]       
            [string]$Script= ""
        )
    if ($Script) {
      try {
        & "Invoke-$Script"
      } catch {
        throw "Failed to call 'Invoke-$Script': $_"
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: I will add that this answer does **not** create a command injection vulnerability, even though it looks like it might. This is because the `&` operator will treat anything passed into the first argument as the literal executable/script names. For example, if you pass `"234; whoami"`, the script will error out instead of executing `Invoke-234` then `whoami`. This prevents anyone who may have access to the `$Script` parameter from just executing whatever they want, which is good.

Comment: Thanks, @spicy.dll; just to make what is implied by your comment explicit: `&` with a dynamically constructed command name / path is the safe alternative to `Invoke-Expression`  (`iex`), whose use is rarely justified and generally [should not be used to invoke an external program or PowerShell command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57966347/45375).