# ssh Bad local forwarding specification when passing port as parameter

Tags: windows, powershell, ssh, port, portforwarding

I created this function in the `.ps1` profile for Windows PowerShell:

```
function sshpc ([int]$port = 8888) {
    ssh -fNL [int]$port:localhost:[int]$port pc
}
```

However, the port forwading command does not work. It prints the message:

> Bad local forwarding specification '[Int][Int]8888'

But running the command `ssh -fNL 8888:localhost:8888 pc` works fine.
How can I make this work?

---

What I tried:

I tried using the parameter definitions: `($port)`, `([int]$port)`, `($port = 8888)` but these also fail.
This function works fine:

```
function sshpc {
    ssh -fNL 8888:localhost:8888 pc
}
```

Comment: You don't need type casting, just remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `[int]$port:localhost:[int]$port`

You cannot use casts this way, and they're also not necessary, given that you can only ever pass *strings* as arguments to external programs (aside from that, `$port` already *is* of type `[int]`).

Instead, use an (implicit) expandable string to compose your argument:

```
ssh -fNL ${port}:localhost:${port}
```

- `${port}:localhost:${port}` is *implicitly* treated as if it were enclosed in `"..."`, i.e. as an [*expandable (interpolating) string*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings) .

  - In other words: `"${port}:localhost:${port}"` works too, and you may prefer it for conceptual clarity and to avoid cases where unquoted arguments *aren't* implicitly treated as expandable strings.

    - E.g., `Write-Output "$baseName.txt"` appends literal `.txt` to the value of `$baseName`, whereas `Write-Output $baseName.txt` tries to access a (nonexistent) `.txt` *property* on the object stored in `$baseName`; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58809351/45375) for background information.
- Note the need to enclose the variable name, `port`, in `{...}` so as to delimit it; without it, the `:` would be considered part of the variable reference, making `$port` the *a scope or namespace prefix* of the following variable reference, which expands to the empty string due to non-existence: `$port:localhost`.

  - This delimiting isn't strictly necessary in the *second* `${port}` reference, but was chosen for symmetry here.
  - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60329476/45375) for background information.