# Saving XML on remote machine using Invoke-Command

Tags: powershell

Basically, I'm loading the XML from my local machine, and then I'm trying to save it on a remote machine using Invoke-Command.

I know I can use Copy-item via UNC path, but it takes too long on some machines, and Invoke-Command is faster - I tested this already.

However, I think I'm passing the argument wrong?

The error I get is:

```
Method invocation failed because [System.String] does not contain a method named 'Save'.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
    + PSComputerName        : -
```

This is how I'm passing it:

```
    foreach ($serverPath in $serverLocations) {

        if ($null -ne $serverPath) {

            $generatedPath = "$(Get-Location)\Generated.ManageSQLJobs.xml" 
            [Xml]$generatedFile = Get-Content $generatedPath


            Write-Log "INFO" "Checking on $serverPath" $ExecutionLogFullPath
            $testPath = Invoke-Command -ComputerName "$serverPath" -ArgumentList [Xml]$generatedFile -ScriptBlock {

                param (
                    $value
                )
                Test-Path -Path "C:\AppData\MonitoringConfig\" 

                if (!$testPath) {
                    $destinationPath = New-Item -Path "C:\AppData\" -Name "MonitoringConfig" -ItemType Directory
                }
                if ($testPath) {
                    $destinationPath = "C:\AppData\MonitoringConfig"
                    #Write-Log "INFO" "Exists on $serverPath." $ExecutionLogFullPath 
                }

                $GetPathToDeleteXML = "C:\AppData\MonitoringConfig\Generated.ManageSQLJobs.xml" 
                if (Test-Path -Path $GetPathToDeleteXML) {
                    Remove-Item -Path * #-Filter Generated.ManageSQLJobs.xml
                }

                $GetPathForXML = "C:\AppData\MonitoringConfig\Generated.ManageSQLJobs.xml" 

                $value.Save($GetPathForXML.fullname)

            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `-ArgumentList [Xml]$generatedFile`

should be (note the `(...)`):

```
-ArgumentList ([Xml]$generatedFile)
```

`[Xml]$generatedFile` isn't recognized as an *expression*, because when PowerShell parses in [*argument mode*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing) (commands with arguments, shell-style), an initial  `[` isn't special.

In effect, your argument is interpreted as an *expandable* string, i.e. as if you had passed
`"[Xml]$generatedFile"`.
Therefore, `$value` in your remotely executed script block received a `[string]` instance, not an `[xml]` instance, and strings don't have a `.Save()` method, which explains the error message.

Enclosing your argument in `(...)` forces its interpretation as an expression.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41254359/45375) for a comprehensive overview of how PowerShell parses unquoted tokens in argument mode.

---

A **general caveat re passing complex objects as arguments to code executed *remotely* / in *background jobs***:

Arguments passed to remote / background script blocks must undergo XML-based serialization and deserialization, because they pass computer / process boundaries.

Only a limited set of known types are deserialized *faithfully* (deserialized as the original type), others are *emulated*.

While `[xml]` instances, `[string]` instances and .NET primitive types such as `[int]` *are* faithfully deserialized, most other types are *not*.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59180367/45375) for more information.

Comment: I'm glad to hear it was helpful, @GhostyIs1337; thanks for the nice feedback.