# Powershell loop that counts down

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to print a warning to let the user know that 0 isn't a valid option for an assignment for class. Just started learning about powershell and can't find any help on how to set a parameter like this.

Assignment is 3.)   Write a loop that calculates $num^2 for each iteration and prints the value using Write-Host. This loop must execute at least once and beginning counting down. When $num = 0, the loop should end. Prevent this loop from receiving $num as 0 as this will cause an infinite loop. If 0 is set as $num, print a warning to let the user know that 0 isn’t a valid option.

So far this is what I have

```bsh
$num=Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter a number'
do
{
   write-host $num
   $num--
}
until($num -eq -1)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Use a while loop and break statement to exit when you need to. There is no squaring in your try

Answer (score 0):

There are two fundamental problems:

- `Read-Host` always returns a *string*, and `--`, the decrement operator, can only be used on *numbers*; you must convert the string to a number first:

  - `[int] $num = Read-Host 'Enter a number'`
- `write-host $num $num--` doesn't work as expected: while the `$num` references are expanded, the trailing `--` is considered a *string literal*, not the decrement operator; to treat `$num--` as an *expression*, you must enclose it in `(...)`; also, to print the already decremented number, reverse the operands:

  - `$num = 42; Write-Host ($num--) $num`  yields `42 41`, as intended.
  - Incorrect: `$num = 42; Write-Host $num $num--` yields `42 42--`
  - The - complex - rules PowerShell uses when parsing unquoted command arguments are summarized in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41254359/45375)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$num = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter a number'
$num = [int]::Parse( $num )

do
{
   write-host "$num square is $([Math]::Pow($num,2))" 
}
while(--$num)
```