# Powershell copy-item using variable source names

Tags: powershell, variables, copy-item

I'm new to PowerShell and still trying to figure things out. I have a script that will successfully copy a file from one location to another:

```
Copy-Item \\ServerName01\FolderName\file_09022020_0030.txt 
    -Destination \\ServerName02\FolderName\file_copied.txt
```

How can I write the script to use a variable source file name? I want to use a variable to find today's date minus 7 days and grab the corresponding file.

EX:

```
Copy-Item \ServerName01\FolderName\file_[variable today minus 7]*.txt 
    -Destination \ServerName02\FolderName\file_copied.txt
```

The variable date should be in the MMDDYYYY format. The timestamp at the end of each file can be ignored so I'm guessing that's a wildcard (*)

A new file is posted each day but the file name follows a pattern:

```
file_09022020_0030.txt
file_09012020_0030.txt
file_08312020_0305.txt
...
file_08262020_0451.txt
file_08252020_0305.txt
file_08242020_0305.txt
```

Comment: Check out help about [variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_variables?view=powershell-7) and use [Get-Date](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-date?view=powershell-7) to pick a date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Get a string representing 7 days ago in the specified format
# and store it in variable $dt
$dt = (Get-Date).AddDays(-7).ToString('MMddyyyy')

# Use variable $dt in the source file path pattern.
Copy-Item -Path        \\ServerName01\FolderName\file_${dt}_*.txt `
          -Destination \\ServerName02\FolderName\file_copied.txt
```

Note the `{...}` around the variable name, `dt`, which is required to tell PowerShell where the variable name ends, given that `_` is a valid character in a variable name.

That said, there's no strict need for an intermediate variable, so instead of `${dt}` you could *directly* embed
`$((Get-Date).AddDays(-7).ToString('MMddyyyy'))` in the source path, via `$()`, the [subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#subexpression-operator--).

See also:

- [`Get-Date`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Get-Date)
- [`System.DateTime.ToString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DateTime.ToString)
- [Using variable references and subexpressions in unquoted command arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41254359/45375).