# How can I use variables in long PowerShell command without breaking the command

Tags: windows, powershell, ffmpeg

I want to use ffmpeg to convert .m4a files in to .mp3 files.

I can do it for each single file, but that takes a lot of effort to type in.

```
ffmpeg -i '.\song.m4a' -ac 2 -b:a 192k '.\song.mp3'
```

Is there a way to do this with powershell using variables?
ex:

```
ffmpeg -i $v -ac 2 -b:a 192k $v.mp3
```

The problem with this is that then the `-ac` flag is taken as part of the path and not of ffmpeg anymore.

Is there a way around this in powershell?
Or could this be done with an array? If I use `$v=Get-ChildItem -Name` and iterate over the array with a foreach loop in to the ffmpeg command.

I am very new to PowerShell and don't have a lot of experience but it seems to me that should be possible to do.

I would appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "the `-ac` flag is taked as part of the path"? Did you try? If you tried and got errors or unexpected behavior, please post the full error messages and/or describe the behavior :)

Answer (score 2):

If you do just `Get-Childitem -Name` you would end up with `song.m4a.mp3` unless you took care of that with a replace statement, etc. If you keep it as an object then you could reference the name and later the basename.

```
get-childitem -Filter *.m4a |
    foreach {ffmpeg -i “$($_.name)“ -ac 2 -b:a 192k “$($_.basename).mp3”}
```

I have not tested this so you may need to adjust the quotes.

Comment: It worked out great thank you.
The "$($_.basname).mp3" does the renaming of the extension right?

Comment: You got it! Basename is the filename without extension and then manually specifying mp3.

Answer (score 1):

$v.mp3 doesn't seem to work. Make a variable set to 'song.mp3' instead. Or use double quotes "$v.mp3".

```
echoargs $v.mp3   # no output


echoargs "$v.mp3"
Arg 0 is <song.mp3>
```

Answer (score 1):

Note:

- Your real problem is not with `-ac`, but with argument `$v.mp3`
- While the immediate fix would be `"$v.mp3"` - i.e. to simply *double-quote* your argument - that would result in *doubled file extensions* (`.mp4.mp3`), for which [Doug Maurer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64361920/45375) offers a fix.

The following focuses generally on **how PowerShell interprets a command-line argument such as `$v.mp3`**.

---

In order for `$v.mp3` to be interpreted as the value of variable `$v` *as a whole* followed by *verbatim text `.mp3`*, you must *double-quote* the argument (`"$v.mp3"`), as shown in [js2010's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64361452/45375).

- A double-quoted, interpolating string in PowerShell is called an *expandable string*, and the syntax rules are covered in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375).

*Unquoted* arguments are *often*, but not always, *implicitly* treated like expandable strings, but **a single variable reference such as `$v` or even a subexpression such as `$($v.BaseName)` or `($v.BaseName)` *followed by something that looks like a property access* or even *method call*** - such as `$v.mp3` here - is a notable exception and is **interpreted as just that**:

- Therefore, PowerShell interprets the `.mp3` part as a *property access*: that is, it tries to return the value of a property named `mp3` of the object stored in variable `$v`; if `$v` contains a *string*, there will be no such property, which means that the expression evaluates to `$null` and no argument at all is passed to the external program (`ffmpeg`).
- **The rules for how PowerShell treats variable references and subexpressions in *unquoted* command-line arguments are complex**:

  - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41254359/45375) for a comprehensive overview.
  - Therefore, **if you know that your argument is meant to be a *string* that mixes variable references and verbatim parts, it's simplest to always use double-quoting**.