# How do I put all the errors from the the catch block into the email Body in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, exception

I'm working on a PowerShell script that sends an email every time and error is encountered. I am trying the convert the $error[0] arraylist into the string but it's giving me the message:

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
```

Here's the chunk of code that I have in my catch block.

```
Catch [Exception]
{
    $Message = New-Object System.Exception "Error: " + $error[0].Exception.InnerException.ToString()
    Send-MailMessage -Port $port -smtpServer $smtpservername -to $to -from $from -subject $subject -body [string] $Message
    throw ($Message)
}
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're incorrectly mixing PowerShell's two [parsing modes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Parsing), *argument* mode (as used in shells) and *expression* mode (as used in programming languages).

**In order to use *expressions* as *arguments* in argument mode (as *command* arguments), you must enclose them in `(...)`**, the [grouping operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#grouping-operator--):<sup>[1]</sup>

```sh
# WRONG
$Message = New-Object System.Exception "Error: " + $error[0].Exception.InnerException.ToString()
```

should be:

```sh
# OK - note the (...) around the string-concatenation operation:
$Message = New-Object System.Exception ("Error: " + $error[0].Exception.InnerException.ToString())
```

Similarly:

```sh
# WRONG
Send-MailMessage -Port $port -smtpServer $smtpservername -to $to -from $from -subject $subject -body [string] $Message
```

should be:

```sh
# OK - note the (...) around the [string] cast.
Send-MailMessage -Port $port -smtpServer $smtpservername -to $to -from $from -subject $subject -body ([string] $Message)
```

For more information on how unquoted tokens are parsed in argument mode, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41254359/45375).

---

<sup>[1] There is one exception: if an argument starts with a variable reference, accessing a *property* of that variable or calling a *method* on it works as-is; e.g.: `Write-Output $HOME.Length` or `Write-Output $HOME.ToLower()`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41254359/45375) for more information.</sup>