# Output list of files to CSV and change file names

Tags: powershell, export-to-csv

I know how to generate a list of files in a directory, for example:

```
get-childitem -path "c:\temp" -Recurse | select-object BaseName, Extension | export-csv -notypeinformation -path "c:\temp\filelist.csv"
```

Now I would like to also manipulate some filenames to clean them up, for example I am trying to do this, but it fails

```
get-childitem -path "c:\temp" -Recurse | select-object BaseName.Replace("_Error_",""), Extension | export-csv -notypeinformation -path "c:\temp\filelist.csv"
```

I get the error similar to this:
Select-Object : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'System.Object[]'.
At line:1 char:207

- ... ontainer} | select-object BaseName.Replace("_",""), Extension | expor ...
- ```
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Select-Object], ParameterBindingException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectObjectCommand

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong?  Isn't "BaseName" a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- As a *direct argument*, `BaseName.Replace("_Error_","")` cannot work if you want to provide an *expression* that operates on *each input object*.

  - Loosely speaking, such an argument is interpreted as an expandable string literal, with `(` starting a *new* argument; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41254359/45375) for how unquoted tokens are parsed as command arguments.
- Instead, you need a [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Calculated_Properties).

```bash
Get-ChildItem -path "c:\temp" -Recurse | 
  Select-Object @{ n='BaseName'; e={ $_.BaseName.Replace("_Error_","") } }, 
                Extension |
  Export-csv -NoTypeInformation -Path c:\temp\filelist.csv
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is complex (for me). One small correction - the code above is missing a second closing curly brace, other then that, it works perfectly. It should be:     Get-ChildItem -path "c:\temp" -Recurse | 
  Select-Object @{ n='BaseName'; e={ $_.BaseName.Replace("_Error_","") }}, Extension |
  Export-csv -NoTypeInformation -Path c:\temp\filelist.csv

Comment: Glad to hear it helped, @SQL_Guy. Thanks for telling me about the missing `}` - answer updated.