# Powershell subexpression doesn't recognize "pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv4" command

Tags: c++, bash, powershell, opencv

I want to compile an OpenCV C/C++ (MSYS2) program on Windows using solely the CLI. The GNU Bash way to do this is (which runs fine on MSYS2 MINGW64 Shell):

```
g++ main.cc -o main `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv4`
```

Bash perfectly recognizes the backticks as a subexpression, however PowerShell doesn't:

```
> g++ main.cc -o main `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv4`
g++.exe: error: unrecognized command-line option '--cflags'
g++.exe: error: unrecognized command-line option '--libs'
```

I've done some research, and the equivalent on PowerShell would be

```
g++ main.cc -o main $(pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv4)
```

Despite `$(pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv4)`  being the right way to write a subexpression in PowerShell as an **echo** command shows it produces the right output (in this case compiler include and linker flags I need):

```
> echo $(pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv4)
-IC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../include/opencv4 -LC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib -lopencv_gapi -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_alphamat -lopencv_aruco -lopencv_barcode -lopencv_bgsegm -lopencv_ccalib -lopencv_cvv -lopencv_dnn_objdetect -lopencv_dnn_superres -lopencv_dpm (...)
```

It simply won't work:

```
> g++ main.cc -o main $(pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv4)
main.cc:1:10: fatal error: opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp: No such file or directory
    1 | #include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Therefore, I need to use a verbose workaround to compile my file:

```
> g++ main.cc -o main -IC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../include/opencv4 -LC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib -lopencv_gapi -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_alphamat -lopencv_aruco -lopencv_barcode -lopencv_bgsegm -lopencv_ccalib -lopencv_cvv -lopencv_dnn_objdetect -lopencv_dnn_superres -lopencv_dpm -lopencv_face -lopencv_freetype -lopencv_fuzzy -lopencv_hdf -lopencv_hfs -lopencv_img_hash (...)
```

My PowerShell version:

```
> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.22621.608
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.22621.608
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

My question is: how can I make this particular subexpression work in PowerShell so that I don't have to resort to the verbose fallback of copying and pasting the output of
`pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv4`  after `g++ main.cc -o main`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The equivalent of your `bash` command is:

```
g++ main.cc -o main (-split (pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv4))
```

That is:

- `(pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv4)` executes your `pkg-config` call, and, by enclosing it in `(...)`, the [grouping operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#grouping-operator--), its output can participate in a larger expression.
- Using the unary form of `-split`, the [string splitting operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split), then splits the `pkg-config` call's output into an *array* of whitespace-separated tokens, which is (part of) the equivalent of what `bash` *implicitly* does via its [shell expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html) called [*word splitting*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Splitting.html).
- Passing an *array* as an argument to an *external program* in PowerShell causes its elements to be passed as *individual arguments*.

---

Note:

- Using `$(...)`, PowerShell's [subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#subexpression-operator--) does *not* work in this case, because its output would be passed *as a whole*, as a *single argument* to the target executable (or, in the case of an external-program call that outputs *multiple* lines, each line *in full* would be passed as an argument).
- **In general, where `bash` requires `$(...)` (or its legacy form `` `...` ``), in PowerShell `(...)` is usually sufficient** (and in *assignments* not even it is needed, e.g., `$var = Get-Date`); the primary use case for `$(...)` in PowerShell is inside `"..."`, i.e. inside [expandable (double-quoted) strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings)
- More fundamentally, **PowerShell has *no* equivalent of `bash`'s [*shell expansions*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html)**:

  - Notably, [*parameter* expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) (e.g. `${var//foo/bar}`) are *not* supported, and require use of *expressions* instead (e.g. `($var -replace 'foo', 'bar')`)
  - ***Unquoted* arguments are *not* generally subject to special interpretation**, except if they contain *metacharacters*, which, if they are to be used *verbatim*, for syntactic reasons then must either be individually `` ` ``-*escaped* (`` ` ``, the so-called *backtick*, is PowerShell's [escape character](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Special_Characters)), or require the whole argument to be enclosed in *quotes*.
  - ***It is up to each target command* to interpret special characters such as an initial `~` as referring to the home directory, or to interpret arguments such as `*.txt` as *wildcard patterns*** - whether such an argument was passed in quotes or not.
  - Variable references (e.g., `$var`) and simple expressions based on them (e.g, `$var.Property`), (grouping) expressions (e.g. (`(1 + 2)`), as well as subexpressions (`$(...)`) and array subexpressions (`@(...)`) can be used *as-is* as arguments, even if what they evaluate to contains *spaces* - in the case of calling *external programs*, on Windows, PowerShell will double-quote the result *on demand*, behind the scenes; as stated, *multiple* outputs are *each* passed as an argument.

    - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41254359/45375) for more information.

Comment: Thank you very much for both the solution and lesson! :)

Comment: My pleasure, @flsantoscc; I've since tweaked the explanation a bit.