# Powershell Docker Command Doesn't Work Like Bat File

Tags: docker, powershell, batch-file

I'm trying to create a script that starts a docker container and mounts a local folder that contains spaces in the name.  I can get it to work fine when I run a *.bat file with the docker run command:

```
docker run -p 8081:8081 -v "C:\Test Folder With Blanks":/zzz myimage jupyter lab --notebook-dir=/zzz--ip=0.0.0.0 --port=8081 --allow-root
```

But when I try to do the same in a Powershell script file, I get an error:

```
$CMD = 'docker run -p 8081:8081 -v "C:\Test Folder With Blanks":/zzz myimage jupyter lab --notebook-dir=/zzz--ip=0.0.0.0 --port=8081 --allow-root'
    
Invoke-Expression $CMD
docker: invalid reference format.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

I'm on Win10 and running Powershell in Visual Studio Code IDE.

Thanks for ideas.

Answer (score 1):

First, the obligatory warning: Unless you have a command line stored as a *single string* somewhere *and* you either *fully control or trust* the content of the string, [`Invoke-Expression` should generally be avoided](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/).

---

**You're seeing an *inconsistency*** in how PowerShell treats compound tokens composed of directly concatenated quoted and unquoted parts.

Specifically, **argument `"C:\Test Folder With Blanks":/zzz` is unexpectedly *broken in two***, i.e passed as *two* arguments.

The **workaround** is to **quote the *entire* argument**, i.e.
`"C:\Test Folder With Blanks:/zzz"`

<sup>Note: I'm assuming that `docker` doesn't actually require *partial* quoting in its arguments, which it shouldn't; however, there are high-profile CLIs on Windows that do, notably `msiexec`.</sup>

Alternatively, use an *expression* enclosed in `(...)` to compose your string; e.g.
`("C:\Test Folder With Blanks" + ':/zzz')`

<sup>There's no good reason to do so in this case, but it could be helpful if you need string interpolation in one part of your string (`"..."`), but not in another (`'...'`).</sup>

**General caveats**:

- Compared to **`cmd.exe`** and also POSIX-compatible shells such as **`bash`**, PowerShell has several *additional* metacharacters, notably `@` (at the start of a token), `{` / `}`, and `;`. Therefore, **you cannot always expect command lines written for these shells to work as-is in PowerShell**.
- As of PowerShell 7.2.2, passing arguments to *external programs* (such as `docker`) is fundamentally broken with respect to arguments that have *embedded* `"` characters and *empty-string* arguments - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59036879/45375).

---

The **general pattern of the inconsistency**, as of PowerShell 7.2.2, is as follows:

If an argument:

- *starts with* a *quoted* token - whether single- (`'...'`) or double-quoted (`"..."`) -
- *and* has additional characters directly following the closing quote,

the first such character starts a *separate argument*.

E.g. `"foo":bar` / `"foo"=bar` / `"foo"'bar'` are passed as separate arguments `foo` and `:bar` / `foo` and `=bar` / `foo` and `bar`, respectively.

In other words:

- **You cannot compose a single string argument from a mix of quoted and unquoted / differently quoted tokens if the *first* token is *quoted***.
- Conversely, it *does* work if the first token is *unquoted*, including an unquoted simple variable reference such as `$HOME`.

```bash
# OK: First token is unquoted.
PS> cmd /c echo foo"bar"'baz'last
foobarbazlast

# !! BROKEN: First token is quoted.
# !!         Because each successive token is quoted too, 
# !!         each becomes its own argument.
PS> cmd /c echo 'foo'"bar"'baz'last
foo bar baz last
```

[GitHub issue #6467](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6467) discusses this inconsistency; however, it has been closed, because the behavior is - surprisingly - considered by design.

---

This does *not* happen if the first token is *unquoted*; however, there are ***related* bugs** that start with *unquoted* tokens that similarly break arguments in two, related to their looking like *named arguments* to PowerShell (which is a PowerShell concept that doesn't apply when calling *external programs*):

- [GitHub issue #11646](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11646): an argument such as `-foo=1,2` breaks parsing.
- [GitHub issue #6291](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6291): an argument such as `-foo=bar.baz` is broken in two at the (first) `.`