# In PowerShell, how to format screen output for a decimal to display 2 places, like this example. I can do in python but not exactly in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, format, output

```
$price = 22.5

write-host "The price is $"("{0:N2}" -f ($price))"!"
```

#NOTE: Prints out-> The price is $ 22.50 ! (Has an EXTRA SPACE after the $ & before the !)

---

I can do it this long way, but it is too much work:
write-host "The price is $" -nonewline
write-host ("{0:N2}" -f ($price)) -nonewline
write-host "!"

Comment: use >>> `write-host ('The price is ${0:N2}' -f $price)` <<< instead of the method you used. note the use of SINGLE quotes and where parens are used. [*grin*]

Comment: `'{0:N2}' -f $price` should be all you really need

Comment: Thanks Lee, that was exactly what I was looking for.  You were informative & concise.

Thanks also to Abraham, that was a nice representation of the simplest form possible.

Comment: Lee, I would have chose your solution as the "Correct Answer" because when you are throwing a script together and have already lost time, your type of answer is a quick relief to the frustration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Has an EXTRA SPACE

The reason is that **you're passing *three* arguments to [`Write-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host)**, which the latter prints separated *with spaces* by default:

- Argument 1: `"The price is $"`
- Argument 2: `("{0:N2}" -f ($price))`
- Argument 3: `"!"`
- Generally, note that in PowerShell you can *not* form a single string argument from directly concatenated quoted strings the way you can in `bash`, for instance, such as with `"foo"'bar'` - unless the first token is *unquoted*, PowerShell will treat the substrings as *separate arguments* - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65380907/45375).

To avoid these spaces, **pass a *single* [expandable (double-quoted) string (`"..."`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings)**, which requires:

- Escaping `$` chars. to be used *verbatim* as `` `$ `` (you only got away without this in your attempt because the `$` happened to be *at the end* of your first argument).
- Enclosing the `"{0:N2}" -f ($price)` expression - which can be simplified to `"{0:N2}" -f $price` - in `$(...)`, the [subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#subexpression-operator--)

```
# Note: No need for Write-Host, unless you explicitly want to print
#       to the *display only*.
"The price is `$$("{0:N2}" -f $price)!"
```

Note:

- [`Write-Host` is typically the wrong tool to use](http://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful/), unless the intent is to write *to the display only*, bypassing the success output stream and with it the ability to send output to other commands, capture it in a variable, or redirect it to a file. To output a value, use it *by itself*; e.g., `$value` instead of `Write-Host $value` (or use `Write-Output $value`, though that is rarely needed); see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60534138/45375).

---

However, [Lee Dailey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3080908/lee-dailey) shows a **simpler alternative** using a single expression with the [`-f`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#format-operator--f) operator, whose LHS can then be a [verbatim (single-quoted) string (`'...'`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#single-quoted-strings):

```
# If you want to use Write-Host, enclose the entire expression in (...)
'The price is ${0:N2}!' -f $price
```

Comment: Thanks mklement0, your perspective is much appreciated.  My attempt to translate a simple statement from python to powershell blew up, so I started to break down the problem, ending up with 3 arguments.  Interesting is your explanation on the expanded string.

Comment: Mklement0, it took me some time to fully appreciate your answer after which it was obvious that you had the best answer.  Your info on write-host limiting output to display was an important lesson to learn, along with the expandable string.

Answer (score 1):

Two alternatives

1. Using format operator [-f](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#format-operator--f)
2. Using [string.Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=net-6.0#system-string-format(system-string-system-object())) Method

**Code**

```
$price = 22.5

$message = "The price is `${0:N2}!" -f $price
Write-Host $message

$message = [System.String]::Format("The price is `${0:N2}!", @($price))
Write-Host $message

Write-Host $("The price is `${0:N2}!" -f $price)
Write-Host $([System.String]::Format("The price is `${0:N2}!", @($price)))

# //Multiple parameters
$customer = "Joma"
Write-Host $("The price is `${0:N2}!. Thanks for your purchase {1}." -f $price, $customer)
Write-Host $([System.String]::Format("The price is `${0:N2}!. Thanks for your purchase {1}.", @($price, "Joma")))
```

**Output**
[image: output]

Comment: Thanks Joma.  Nice set of examples with output.  I will add these lessons to my knowledge base.

Comment: Your visual representation really hit home with me, as I am a visual learner.  However, after much consideration, I had to choose Mklement0's answer as there was just so much information.  In reading all of these responses, I now see why you put the formatted information to variable, so as not to limit the output to the display.  Keep up your great visual answers, as they are a sure fire way to show programmers of all levels how to accomplish their goals.  Please consider providing some explanation below the visual solution to clarify any key points.  The links were helpful. Thanks!

Comment: @colemd1, I only contribute with my grain of sand.

Comment: Keep it up, the examples you provided are great!  You are obviously a knowledgeable individual.