# Powershell Get-Content - variable File

Tags: powershell, variables, syntax

I need to change the encoding of a file from UTF8-BOM to UTF8 different files where the date is different. I have a variable with the Data that I need but I have problems passing that variable to the Get-Content param.

```
$Today = Get-Date -Format "yyyyMMdd"
Get-Content 'D:\Folder_1\Test_file.'+$(${Today})+'.csv' | Set-Content -Encoding Ascii 'D:\Folder_2\Test_file.'+$(${Today})+'.csv'
```

The file names are "Test_file.20220923.csv" for example.

The error:

> Get-Content : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '+20220923+.

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 1):

- `'D:\Folder_1\Test_file.'+$(${Today})+'.csv'` is an *expression* (a string concatenation via the `+` operator).
- **In order to pass an expression as an *argument* to a command, you must enclose it in `(...)`**, the [grouping operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#grouping-operator--).<sup>[1]</sup>

Therefore (applies analogously to your `Set-Content` call):

```bash
Get-Content ('D:\Folder_1\Test_file.'+${Today}+'.csv')
```

Note that I've omitted the unnecessary use of `$(...)`, the [subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#subexpression-operator--), which is typically only needed inside [expandable (double-quoted) string (`"..."`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings), and then only for embedding expressions or commands (a variable reference such as `$Today` by itself can be embedded as-is).

The equivalent command using an expandable string:

```bash
Get-Content "D:\Folder_1\Test_file.${Today}.csv"
```

---

As for **what you tried**:

```bash
# WRONG: Passes *two* arguments.
Get-Content 'D:\Folder_1\Test_file.'+$(${Today})+'.csv'
```

Even though `'D:\Folder_1\Test_file.'+$(${Today})+'.csv'` contains no spaces, PowerShell breaks this compound token into *two* arguments, verbatim `D:\Folder_1\Test_file.` and (for instance) verbatim `+20220923+.csv`.<sup>[2]</sup>

It is the latter, i.e. the *extra* positional argument causes [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) to report an error, because it only supports *one* positional argument (which binds to its `-Path` parameter).

---

<sup>[1] `$(...)` is often seen in practice instead, but `$(...)` is only ever needed in two cases: (a) to embed entire *statement(s)*, notably loops and conditionals, in another statement, and (b) to embed an expression, command, or statement(s) inside `"..."`, an expandable (interpolating) string. Just `(...)` is enough to pass a single *command* or *expression* as a command argument. While not likely, the unnecessary use of `$(...)` can have side effects - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58248195/45375).</sup>

<sup>[2] In case you're wondering how a compound token such as `'D:\Folder_1\Test_file.'+${Today}+'.csv'` is parsed and results in these two arguments, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65380907/45375).</sup>