# Can I get this FOREACH loop to work in Windows Powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell, foreach, wget

I'm trying to use a foreach loop in Windows Powershell to download some images and I think I'm close, but I can't seem to get it right.

The command:

```
foreach ($name in @('avatar_1', 'avatar_2', 'avatar_3', 'avatar_4', 'avatar_5', 'avatar_6', 'avatar_7', 'thumbnail_1'))
>> {
>> wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/flutter/codelabs/main/animated-responsive-layout/step_04/assets/$name.png -O $name.png
>> }
```

It seems to loop through the list, but it just results in the below for each item:

```
StatusCode        : 200
StatusDescription : OK
Content           : {137, 80, 78, 71...}
RawContent        : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
                    Connection: keep-alive
                    Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'; style-src 'unsafe-inline'; sandbox
                    Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
                    X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
                    ...
Headers           : {[Connection, keep-alive], [Content-Security-Policy, default-src 'none'; style-src 'unsafe-inline'; sandbox], [Strict-Transport-Security, max-age=31536000],
                    [X-Content-Type-Options, nosniff]...}
RawContentLength  : 61683
```

I know the command works as `wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/flutter/codelabs/main/animated-responsive-layout/step_04/assets/avatar_1.png -O avatar_1.png` will download the image. I'm not sure if I'm using the $name variable correctly in the foreach loop. I don't really use Powershell that often but ran into the command during a codelab and I was interested in getting it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the updated version of your script. This worked fine for me.

```
foreach ($name in @('avatar_1', 'avatar_2', 'avatar_3', 'avatar_4', 'avatar_5', 'avatar_6', 'avatar_7', 'thumbnail_1'))
{
    $url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/flutter/codelabs/main/animated-responsive-layout/step_04/assets/${name}.png"
    $outputFile = "${name}.png"
    Invoke-WebRequest $url -OutFile $outputFile
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me as well and it seems what I was missing was the combination of putting the URL and out file in quotes and adding the curly brackets around the `$name` variable. Solved!

Comment: @Natzely, glad to hear your issue is solved, but the `{...}` enclosure is _not_ needed in this case (though you may choose to use it for visual clarity), because in string interpolation (inside `"..."`) a `.` isn't considered a part of a variable name. By contrast, `.` in the _unquoted_ argument `$name.png` is the _member-access operator_, which is why the argument failed (the `$name` value has no property named `png`, resulting in `$null`). Therefore, the only thing needed to make your original code work is to replace `-O $name.png` with `-O "$name.png"`

Comment: @Natzely, I forgot to mention that `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/flutter/codelabs/main/animated-responsive-layout/step_04/assets/$name.png` is _implicitly treated as if it were enclosed in `"..."`_, whereas `$name.png` _in isolation_ is not.

Comment: @Aswin P.M: While your answer is an _effective_ solution, it (a) introduces _incidental variations_ to the code in the question (switch from `wget` to `Invoke-WebRequest`) _without explaining why_ and (b) _bypasses_ the problem with the code in the question _without explaining how_. In short: it solves the very specific problem in the question, but doesn't promote an understanding of what the _general_ problem with the approach in the OP is. As noted, the `{...}` enclosure too is _incidental_ to the solution.

Comment: @mklement0 Thank you for the explanation! Helped me understand what the actual issue was.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @Natzely. If you believe others will benefit from the explanation too, consider up-voting my answer, which offers a more detailed form of the same explanation.

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr**

- **Replace `-O $name.png` with `-O "$name.png"` to prevent the `.png` part from being interpreted as a *property access*** (which evaluates to `$null`, given that the `[string]` instance stored in `$name` has no property named `png`).
- To predictably ensure that an argument you mean to be a *string* composed of a *mix of variable references and verbatim parts* is always passed as such, enclose it in  `"..."`.

---

You've run into a **subtlety in PowerShell's parameter parsing**, i.e. in how PowerShell parses parameter values (arguments) in [argument(-parsing) mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Parsing#argument-mode):

- `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/.../$name.png` - due to *not starting with `$`* - is implicitly treated *as if were enclosed in `"..."`*, i.e. as a [expandable (double-quoted) string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings).

  - In other words: the above is equivalent to `"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/.../$name.png"`, causing the reference to variable `$name` to be expanded *in isolation*, with `.png` being considered a *verbatim* part of the string. (See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375) for a concise summary of PowerShell's string-interpolation rules).
- By contrast, `$name.png` - due to *starting with `$`* - is interpreted as a *member-access expression*, i.e. the attempt to access a *`.png` property* on the object stored in variable `$name`.

  - Given that `$name` contains a *string* and that strings do not have a `.png` property, the expression evaluated to `$null`, which with *external programs* results in *no* argument getting passed.
  - Passing `"$name.png"` yields the desired result via explicit string interpolation; that is, the value of variable `$name` is followed by verbatim string `.png`

---

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried replacing line with this?

```
wget “https://raw.githubusercontent.com/flutter/codelabs/main/animated-responsive-layout/step_04/assets/“ + $name + “.png -O “ + $name + “.png”
```

Comment: After switching it this format, I now get a `Invoke-WebRequest : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '+'.` error

Comment: Your syntax is broken, because passing an _expression_ (such as involving `+` operations) requires enclosure in `(...)` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73832199/45375) for details.