# Powershell Variable assigning issue

Tags: powershell

I am attemping to make the Destination from the Copy Item function be the $path and keep running into syntax error.

```
Function movefiles($dayhash){
    foreach ($h in $dayhash.GetEnumerator() )
    {
        $path = "$formsfolderDaily Checklists\$today_($h.Value)"
        Copy-Item $formsfolder$($h.Value) -Destination $formsfolder"Daily Checklists\"$today"_"$($h.Value)
        editDate($path)
    }
```

Desired outcome

```
Function movefiles($dayhash){
    foreach ($h in $dayhash.GetEnumerator() )
    {
        $path = $formsfolder + "Daily Checklists\" + $today + "_" + ($h.Value)
        Copy-Item $formsfolder$($h.Value) -Destination $path
        editDate($path)
    }
```

Comment: at first glance, in `$path`, you're missing `$` => `\$today_$($h.Value)"`

Comment: "*keep running into syntax error*". Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73840134/edit) the question and add the exact error message to the question.

Answer (score 2):

`$path = "$formsfolderDaily Checklists\$today_($h.Value)"`

This makes me think `$FormsFolder` is a path variable with a trailing backslash -- BUT THAT'S JUST A GUESS -- and one of the reasons Join-Path is so useful.

It's also hard to know what is a literal and what is part of a variblbe name when you start constructing complex expansion strings. I would recommend using the [-f (Format operator)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.1#format-operator--f) which nicely separates the literal and variable portions of your string. My best guess for the above would be:

- `$path = '{0}Daily Checklists\{1}_{2}' -f $formsfolder, $today, $h.Value`

Your template string is on the the left-hand side of the operator, with zero-indexed placeholders in the format `{0}`, `{1}`, etc. The placeholders correspond to the variables/expressions/function calls found in the list on the right-hand side of the operator.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like **you want to implement your solution using [expandable (double-quoted) strings (`"..."`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings)**.

To that end, you need to observe **two fundamental rules**:

- In order to ***disambiguate* variable names from subsequent characters**, enclose their names in `{...}`, e.g. `$[today}` instead of just `$today`

  - Notably, `_` is a legitimate character in a PowerShell variable name, so if a `_` follows a variable reference `{...}` is needed too.
- In order **to embed *expressions*** - such as `$h.Value` - inside `"..."`, **enclose them in `$(...)`**, the [subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#subexpression-operator--)

  - You've done this *in part* in your question, but the first command is missing the `$` before `(`.
- For a complete overview of PowerShell's string-interpolation rules, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375).

Additionally:

- **You're using *compound tokens* composed of *unquoted* and *quoted* parts in order to form a *single* string argument, which is *best avoided*** in PowerShell - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65380907/45375).
- Instead, **use a *single*, `"..."`-enclosed string**.

Therefore (the assumption is that the value of `$formsfolder` ends in `\` (or `/`)):

```
Function movefiles($dayhash) {
  foreach ($h in $dayhash.GetEnumerator() ) {
    $path = "${formsfolder}Daily Checklists\$today_$($h.Value)"
    Copy-Item "${formsfolder}$($h.Value)" -Destination "${formsfolder}Daily Checklists\${today}_$($h.Value)"
    editDate $path
  }
```