# curl: option --upload-file: requires parameter

Tags: powershell, curl, github-actions

Running curl command in Github-actions on windows image.

```
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: build dists
        run: |
          curl.exe -i --user "${{secrets.User}}:${{secrets.Password}}" -H "X-Checksum-Md5:$MD5SUM" -X PUT "${{ env.URL }}\${{ env.PATH }}\$FILE_NAME\${{ github.sha }}.zip" --upload-file $FILE_NAME.zip
```

I am receiving the error `curl: option --upload-file: requires parameter`

I am unable to find what parameter I am missing. I have checked the curl man page and scoured the internet and I have found no answer.

I have changed the formation of the curl inputs.

`curl.exe -i --user "${{secrets.User}}:${{secrets.Password}}" -H "X-Checksum-Md5:$MD5SUM" --upload-file $FILE_NAME.zip "${{ env.URL }}\${{ env.PATH }}\$FILE_NAME\${{ github.sha }}.zip"`

This change results in the error `curl: no URL specified!`

Comment: Use Invoke.  Make the argument list a separate variable : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?force_isolation=true&view=powershell-7.3

Comment: @jdweng, use of `Invoke-Comand` is never needed for local invocation of commands, including external programs, and its use would make no difference here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**tl;dr**

PowerShell interprets **`$FILE_NAME.zip`** as trying to **get the value of a *property named `zip`*** of the object stored in variable `$FILE_NAME`.

**To treat the `.zip` part *literally***, as you intend, you have the following **options**:

- Use **`"$FILE_NAME.zip"`**, i.e. explicitly make it an [expandable (double-quoted) string](https://learn.mxicrosoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings)

  - Inside `"..."`, `.` has no special meaning, except if inside an embedded *subexpression* (`$(...)`) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375) for a systematic overview of the interpolation rules of expandable strings.
  - Even *selective* double-quoting would work - `$FILE_NAME".zip"` - but such *compound* string arguments are tricky in PowerShell, because they only work as intended if the first component is *unquoted* - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65380907/45375).
- Use **`` $FILE_NAME`.zip ``**, i.e. *escape* the `.` character, using `` ` ``, the so-called *backtick*, PowerShell's [escape character](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Special_Characters).
- ***If appropriate*, use `.\$FILE_NAME.zip`** - starting the argument with a character *other than `$`* in essence treats it *as if it were enclosed in `"..."`*.

Therefore, using the first option (note the `"$FILE_NAME.zip"` at the end):

```
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: build dists
        run: |
          curl.exe -i --user "${{secrets.User}}:${{secrets.Password}}" -H "X-Checksum-Md5:$MD5SUM" -X PUT "${{ env.URL }}\${{ env.PATH }}\$FILE_NAME\${{ github.sha }}.zip" --upload-file "$FILE_NAME.zip"
```

---

##### Background information:

`$FILE_NAME.zip` is parsed as a *property access*; that is, an attempt is made to retrieve the value of a property named `zip` on whatever object the `$FILE_NAME` variable contains.

Since a string object has no `.zip` property, PowerShell returns `$null`, which, when passed as an argument to an external program such as `curl`, in effect passes *no argument at all*, which explains the errors you saw.

Note that if your argument didn't *start* with `$FILE_NAME`, it would *implicitly* have been treated like an expandable string; therefore, an alternative to `"$FILE_NAME.zip"` is to use `.\$FILE_NAME.zip` in this case.

The rules for how PowerShell interprets unquoted tokens as command arguments are complex - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41254359/45375) for a systematic overview.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @KurtYTR.