# Powershell: Using Invoke-WebRequest with variables

Tags: json, powershell

I am currently having a problem with a script to send fuel transactions through an api. It works without variables:

```
$headers=@{}
$headers.Add("accept", "application/json")
$headers.Add("content-type", "application/json")
$headers.Add("authorization", "$APIToken")
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://api.samsara.com/fuel-purchase' -Method POST -Headers $headers -ContentType 'application/json' -Body '{"fuelQuantityLiters":"676.8","iftaFuelType":"Diesel","transactionLocation":"350 Rhode Island St, San Francisco, CA 94103","transactionPrice":{"amount":"640.2","currency":"usd"},"transactionReference":"5454534","transactionTime":"2024-02-22T10:20:50.52-06:00","vehicleId":"570"}'
```

But, with variables I get errors.

```
# A POSITIONAL PARAMETER CANNOT BE FOUND THAT ACCEPTS ARGUMENT ("" Around Body)
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://api.samsara.com/fuel-purchase' -Method POST -Headers $headers -ContentType 'application/json' -Body "{"fuelQuantityLiters":$QuantityLiters,"iftaFuelType":$FuelType,"transactionLocation":$StationAddress,"transactionPrice":{"amount":$TransactionSale,"currency":$Currency},"transactionReference":$TransactionID,"transactionTime":$TransactionDateTime,"vehicleId":$Vehicle}"

# INVALID CHARACTER '$' LOOKING FOR BEGINNING OF VALUE ('' Around Body)
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://api.samsara.com/fuel-purchase' -Method POST -Headers $headers -ContentType 'application/json' -Body '{"fuelQuantityLiters":$QuantityLiters,"iftaFuelType":$FuelType,"transactionLocation":$StationAddress,"transactionPrice":{"amount":$TransactionSale,"currency":$Currency},"transactionReference":$TransactionID,"transactionTime":$TransactionDateTime,"vehicleId":$Vehicle}'
```

I figure it has to do with the quotations, but I'm not sure where I need to fix it. Here is the page with the api details about what I'm doing:
https://developers.samsara.com/reference/postfuelpurchase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I figure it has to do with the quotations [quotation marks]

Indeed, your only immediate problem is that **you neglected to *escape* the `"` characters** that you're trying to *embed* in your [*expandable* (interpolating), double-quoted string (`"..."`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings) - **use `` `" `` (or `""`)** for that:

```bash
# Note the use of `" inside the overall "..."
Invoke-WebRequest ... -Body "{`"fuelQuantityLiters`": ... }"
```

- When you neglected to escape embedded `"`, what you meant to be a single string inadvertently became *two* arguments, which triggered the error you saw.<sup>[1]</sup>

Since you require expansion (string interpolation), use of a [*verbatim* (single-quoted string (`'...'`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#single-quoted-strings) for overall enclosure of your `-Body` argument is *not* an option.

- When you tried that, attempted variable references such as `$QuantityLiters` were simply sent *verbatim* to your web service, which failed.

---

However, as others have noted, you're better off defining the input data as a [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables) (`@{ ... }`), and letting [`ConvertTo-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json) create the JSON representation for you:

```bash
Invoke-WebRequest ... -Body (
   @{ fuelQuantityLiters = $QuantityLiters; iftaFuelType = "Diesel" <# ; ... #> } |
   ConvertTo-Json
)
```

---

<sup>[1] The reason is a quirk in how PowerShell parses *compound* string arguments, which you accidentally used: a token such as `"{"foo": "bar"}"` is composed of five adjacent string literals: `"{"`, `foo`, `": "`, `bar`, and `"}"`). Instead of simply *concatenating them*, as Bash would for instance, PowerShell splits them into *two* arguments, `{` and `foo: bar}`, solely because the *first* substring is *quoted*(`"{"`); because the subsequent substring, `foo`, *isn't* quoted, it, along with all remaining substrings *is* concatenated. The syntactic quotes (`"`) are removed in the process, as usual. You can verify this behavior via `Write-Output "{"foo": "bar"}"`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65380907/45375) for more information.</sup>

Comment: Thank you to everyone! All of the answers helped me out a lot and got things working.

Answer (score 0):

You could try constructing the request-body JSON from a hashtable like this -

```
$fuelQuantityLiters   = 676.8
$iftaFuelType         = "Diesel"
$transactionLocation  = "350 Rhode Island St, San Francisco, CA 94103"
$amount               = 676.8
$currency             = "usd"
$transactionReference = "5454534"
$transactionTime      = "2024-02-22T10:20:50.52-06:00"
$vehicleId            = 570

# Separate hashtable for the nested bit
$tranHASH = @{}
$tranHASH.add("amount",   $amount)
$tranHASH.add("currency", $currency)

$restHASH = @{}
$restHASH.add("fuelQuantityLiters",  $fuelQuantityLiters)
$restHASH.add("iftaFuelType",        $iftaFuelType)
$restHASH.add("transactionLocation", $transactionLocation)

# Add in the previous hashtable to create the nesting
$restHASH.add("transactionPrice",    $tranHASH)
$restHASH.add("transactionReference",$transactionReference)
$restHASH.add("transactionTime",     $transactionTime)
$restHASH.add("vehicleId",           $vehicleId)

$JSON = $restHASH | ConvertTo-JSON -compress
```

That yields the JSON you're after for the request body, then pass that to the API

```
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://api.samsara.com/fuel-purchase' -Method POST -Headers $headers -ContentType 'application/json' -Body $JSON
```

Now the -BODY parameter is passed a single argument instead of the command line being awash with quotes.

Answer (score 0):

In general, I find it is better to define everything ahead of time and just pass variables as parameters to Invoke-WebRequest.

I don't have your situation to test this, but below is code similar to what I've been using for our own servers:

```
$uri = 'https://api.samsara.com/fuel-purchase'
$contentType = "application/json"
$headers = @{
   accept = $contentType
   "content-type" = $contentType
   authorization = "$APIToken"
}
$body = @{
   fuelQuantityLiters   = $QuantityLiters
   iftaFuelType         = $FuelType
   transactionLocation  = $StationAddress
   transactionPrice     = @{
      amount   = $TransactionSale
      currency = $Currency
   }
   transactionReference = $TransactionID
   transactionTime      = $TransactionDateTime
   vehicleId            = $Vehicle
} | ConvertTo-Json
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -Method POST -Headers $headers -ContentType $contentType -Body $body
```