# PowerShell formatting for a string

Tags: powershell, string-interpolation, quoting

I have a string that I want to insert dynamically a variable. Example;

```
$tag = '{"number" = "5", "application" = "test","color" = "blue", "class" = "Java"}'
```

I want to accomplish:

```
$mynumber= 2
$tag = '{"number" = "$($mynumber)", "application" = "test","color" = "blue", "class" = "Java"}'
```

I want to have the variable inserted on the string, *but* it is not going through. I guess the '' sets all as a string. Any recommendations on how should I approach this?

PowerShell test and trial and error. Also Google.

Comment: What do you mean by *"PowerShell test and trial and error. Also Google."*? Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add to [Mathias' helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71604329/45375):

- Mistakenly expecting string interpolation inside `'...'` strings (as opposed to inside `"..."`) has come up many times before, and questions such as yours are often closed as a  duplicate of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12394041/45375).
- However, your question is worth answering separately, because:

  - Your use case introduces a follow-up problem, namely that *embedded* `"` characters cannot be used as-is inside `"..."`.
  - More generally, the linked post is in the context of *argument-passing*, where additional rules apply.

---

Note: Some links below are to the relevant sections of the conceptual [about_Quoting_Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules) help topic.

In PowerShell:

- **only `"..."` strings** (double-quoted, called [*expandable strings*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings)) **perform string interpolation**, i.e. expansion of variable values (e.g. `"... $var"` and subexpressions (e.g., `"... $($var.Prop)"`)
- *not* `'...'` strings (single-quoted, called [*verbatim strings*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#single-quoted-strings)), whose values are used *verbatim* (literally).

With `"..."`, **if the string value *itself* contains `"` chars.**:

- *either* **escape them as `` `" `` or `""`**

  - E.g., with `` `" ``; note that while use of `$(...)`, the [subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#subexpression-operator--) never hurts (e.g. `$($mynumber)`), it isn't necessary with *stand-alone* variable references such as `$mynumber`:

    ```bash
    $mynumber= 2
    $tag = "{`"number`" = `"$mynumber`", `"application`" = `"test`",`"color`" = `"blue`", `"class`" = `"Java`"}"
    ```
  - Similarly, if you want **to selectively *suppress* string interpolation**, escape `$` as **`` `$ ``**

    ```bash
    # Note the ` before the first $mynumber.
    # -> '$mynumber = 2'
    $mynumber = 2; "`$mynumber` = $mynumber"
    ```
  - See the conceptual [about_Special_Characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Special_Characters) help topic for info on escaping and escape sequences.
  - If you need to **embed `'` inside `'...'`, use `''`**, or use a (single-quoted) here-string (see next).
- *or* **use a double-quoted [*here-string*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#here-strings)** instead (`@"<newline>...<newline>"@`):

  - See Mathias' answer, but generally note the *strict, multiline syntax* of here-strings:

    - Nothing (except whitespace) must follow the opening delimiter on the same line (`@"` / `@'`)
    - The closing delimiter (`"@` / `'@`) must be *at the very start* of the line - not even whitespace may come before it.

Related answers:

- [Overview of PowerShell's *expandable strings*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375)
- [Overview of *all* forms of *string literals* in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55614306/45375)
- When passing strings as *command arguments*, they are situationally *implicitly* treated like expandable strings (i.e. as if they were `"..."`-enclosed); e.g.

  `Write-Output $HOME\projects` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70041313/45375).

---

***Alternatives* to string interpolation:**

Situationally, other approaches to constructing a string dynamically can be useful:

- Use a (verbatim) *template* string with *placeholders*, with `-f`, the [format operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#format-operator--f):

  ```bash
  $mynumber= 2
  # {0} is the placeholder for the first RHS operand ({1} for the 2nd, ...)
  '"number" = "{0}", ...' -f $mynumber # -> "number" = "2", ...
  ```
- Use simple *string concatenation* with the `+` operator:

  ```bash
  $mynumber= 2
  '"number" = "' + $mynumber + '", ...' # -> "number" = "2", ...
  ```

Comment: Huge thanks for the time and the explanation. I now understand why the string interpolation works on this specific case. I also tried the -f operator but did not insert the ` character on it. I always use the verbatim on C#.

Answer (score 4):

The reason your current attempt doesn't work is that single-quoted (`'`) string literals in PowerShell are *verbatim strings* - no attempt will be made at expanding subexpression pipelines or variable expressions.

If you want an expandable string literal without having to escape all the double-quotes (`"`) contained in the string itself, use a here-string:

```
$mynumber = 2

$tag = @"
{"number" = "$($mynumber)", "application" = "test","color" = "blue", "class" = "Java"}
"@
```