# how do I use powershell variable in AWS CLI command

Tags: powershell, variables, string-interpolation, powershell-7.0

I am trying to run AWS CLI in Powershell 7 with a JSON string as parameter. [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-parameters-quoting-strings.html) make it seem straightforward:

```
aws route53 ... --change-batch '{"Changes":[{"Action":"UPSERT"}]}'
```

however, I get an error:

> Error parsing parameter '--change-batch': Invalid JSON: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
> JSON received: {Changes:[{Action:UPSERT ...

So, it looks like double quotes are stripped at some point.

If I escape the quotes, command works:

```
aws route53 ... --change-batch '{\"Changes\":[{\"Action\":\"UPSERT\"}]}'
```

Now, I am trying to use a variable:

```
aws route53 ... --change-batch '{\"Changes\":[{\"Action\":\"UPSERT\", \"Value\":\"$MY_IP\"}]}'
```

but the variable is not resolved; that is, `$MY_IP` is passed to the server. I tried putting the whole string in double-quotes - but it looks like with double quotes internal quotes are removed even if I escape them. Also with backticks - it works as command continuation. I am looking at [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7) - but the results I am getting are clearly different.

I don't think the problem has anything to do with AWS, but AWS CLI gave me a super twisted test case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Fundamentally, PowerShell only performs string interpolation in *double*-quoted strings (`"..."`), also known as [*expandable strings*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings): see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71605640/45375).
- The surprising and unfortunate need to explicitly `\`-escape embedded `"` chars. in arguments *for external programs* applies irrespective of which quoting style you use, up to at least PowerShell 7.2.x: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66837948/45375).

Thus, since you need a `"..."` string for string interpolation (so that variable reference `$MY_IP` is expanded to its value), you need *two* layers of escaping of embedded `"`:

- `` `" `` (or `""`) in order to satisfy PowerShell's syntax requirements...
- ... and this escape sequence must additionally be escaped with `\` in order for the external program to see the embedded `"` as such.

Therefore:

```bash
# Inside "...", pass-through " must be escaped as \`" (sic)
aws route53 ... --change-batch "{\`"Changes\`":[{\`"Action\`":\"`UPSERT\`", \`"Value\`":\`"$MY_IP\`"}]}"
```

You can ease the pain with the help of an (expandable) [*here-string*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#here-strings), which obviates the need to escape the embedded `"` for *PowerShell*'s sake:

```bash
# A here-string obviates the need to escape " for PowerShell's sake.
aws route53 ... --change-batch @"
{\"Changes\":[{\"Action\":\"UPSERT\", \"Value\":\"$MY_IP\"}]}
"@
```

Another option is to perform the `\`-escaping after the fact, programmatically:

```bash
aws route53 ... --change-batch (@"
{"Changes":[{"Action":"UPSERT", "Value":"$MY_IP"}]}
"@ -replace '"', '\"')
```

Comment: @Felix :) The need for the extra ``\``-escaping is definitely obscure and a nuisance since v1 - a fix is being tested (as an experimental feature in preview versions of 7.3), but it may be opt-in when it becomes official. If it weren't for this, all you'd need to remember is that in PowerShell `\`` is the escape character, not ``\``  - the distinction between `'...'` (verbatim) and `"..."` (interpolating) strings is more or less the same.

Comment: Now, if only somebody could tell AWS to updated their docs!

Comment: @Felix, yeah, that seems broken - there's an `Edit this page on GitHub` link at the bottom, though... - https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-cli-user-guide/tree/master/doc_source/cli-usage-parameters-quoting-strings.md

Comment: I upgraded to powershell 7.3 - and as you said, it is much cleaner!